# Как правильно уменьшить размер стека?

Tags: c#

Как правильно уменьшить размер стека для .NET приложения? Возможно есть какие либо директивы или опции в Visual Studio.

Comment: Хм. А зачем? Для чего такое вдруг понадобилось?

Comment: Для увеличения числа потоков. По умолчанию поднимается в районе 2000 потоков. Согласно статье Раймонда Чена: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/29/444912.aspx ему удалось преодолеть этот порог увеличив стек. Но там пример для плюсов, не знаю как его применить к Task (с опцией шедулера LongRunning).

Comment: Везде предлагаются решения либо для C++ либо софт для реверсинга, с помощью которого ковыряют .exe. Считаю это несколько неправильным.

Comment: Так, уже теплее. А зачем вам 2000 потоков? Может быть, лучше перейти на async/await?

Comment: @VladD, серверное многопоточное TCP приложение. Этим все сказано.

Comment: (1) Для увеличения количества потоков нужно по идее не увеличить, а _уменьшить_ стек. (2) Всё равно непонятно, почему не async/await. TCP-сервер вполне можно писать на async/await. Выделять на каждый запрос по потоку — слишком дорогой вариант.

Comment: Затем, чтобы обойти лимит на адресное пространство, лучше по идее компилироваться под x64.

Comment: Приложение уже x64. Спасибо что поправили по уменьшению размера стека. Но остается открытым вопрос - как манипулировать размером стека не прибегая к реверсингу .exe?

Comment: Но всё же, мне кажется, вы идёте неверным путём. Выделять отдельный поток каждому реквесту **очень** накладно, и вы тем самым налагаете жёсткое ограничение на количество одновременных запросов. Вас можно будет легко заДОСить, просто открыв 20000 соединений и медленно отвечая на запросы. Почему всё же на async/await?

Comment: @VladD, я не пишу сервер. Я пишу клиент.

Comment: Хорошо, клиент. Но вопрос остаётся.

Comment: Возьмем к примеру обычный TCP сканер портов. Почему же для увеличения производительности в них не используют Async\Await?

Comment: Например, потому, что он написан давно? Мой коллега, который писал очень много сетевого кода ещё на C++, не пользовался отдельными потоками из-за неэффективности, а строил state machine вручную. На C# 5+ за вас её построит за кулисами async-метод.

Comment: Для сканера портов проблем вообще нету. Вы запускаете одновременно n `Task`'ов, каждый из которых стучится в порт. Всё будет летать по идее даже на одном потоке, если вы не будете пользоваться блокирующими функциями.

Comment: Попробуйте сами [`ConnectAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194211%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), вы удивитесь :) Потоки не нужны.

Comment: @VladD, вы привели дефолтный метод TcpClient-а. Я просто привел сканер портов как пример. Возьмем же приложение посложнее, с TCP\TLS соединениями, в отдельной сборке. Причем часть приложения в нативном коде. В данный момент менять потоки на async\await нет смысла. Тем более в части приложения используется работа с разными доменами.

Comment: Мне сложно говорить по поводу конкретно вашего приложения, но для хорошего сетевого кода _очень_ нетипична синхронная обработка в отдельных потоках. Я бы не советовал идти этим путём, а вместо этого «асинхронизировать» ваше приложение. Но вам, как архитектору проекта, в любом случае виднее.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы можете, например, воспользоваться [конструктором `Thread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5cykbwz4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) с указанием максимального размера стека.

---

Если вы планируете запускать `Task` на этом потоке, имеет смысл реализовать TaskScheduler, который перекинет `Task` в этот поток.

Или можно воспользоваться готовым scheduler'ом, например, WPF.

---

Пример кода:

При помощи этого метода можно «перебросить» async-метод в поток, на котором бежит данный WPF-диспетчер:

```
static class AsyncHelper
{
    public static DispatcherRedirector RedirectTo(Dispatcher d)
    {
        return new DispatcherRedirector(d);
    }
}

// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx
public struct DispatcherRedirector : INotifyCompletion
{
    public DispatcherRedirector(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    #region awaiter
    public DispatcherRedirector GetAwaiter()
    {
        // combined awaiter and awaitable
        return this;
    }
    #endregion

    #region awaitable
    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get
        {
            // true means execute continuation inline
            return dispatcher.CheckAccess();
        }
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(continuation);
    }

    public void GetResult() { }
    #endregion

    Dispatcher dispatcher;
}
```

Теперь вам нужен поток, в котором бежит диспетчер.

```
public class DispatcherThread : IDisposable
{
    public Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; private set; }
    public TaskScheduler TaskScheduler { get; private set; }

    Thread thread;

    public DispatcherThread(int maxStackSize)
    {
        using (var barrier = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        {
            thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                barrier.Set();
                Dispatcher.Run();
            }, maxStackSize);

            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            barrier.WaitOne();
        }

        TaskScheduler = Get(() => TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // остальные функции вам не нужны для вашей задачи, но могут пригодиться впоследствии
    public void Execute(Action a)
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            a();
        else
            Dispatcher.Invoke(a);
    }

    public void FireAndForget(Action a)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(a);
    }

    public T Get<T>(Func<T> getter)
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            return getter();
        else
        {
            T t = default(T);
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { t = getter(); }));
            return t;
        }
    }

    public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Func<T> getter)
    {
        return Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(getter).Task;
    }

    public Task StartNewTask(Action action)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    action: action,
                    cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None,
                    creationOptions: TaskCreationOptions.None,
                    scheduler: TaskScheduler);
    }

    public Task<T> StartNewTask<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    function: function,
                    cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None,
                    creationOptions: TaskCreationOptions.None,
                    scheduler: TaskScheduler);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        if (thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
            thread.Join();
    }
}
```

Этим можно пользоваться, например, так:

```
using (var t = new DispatcherThread(maxStackSize))
{
    await AsyncHelper.RedirectTo(t.Dispatcher);
    // остаток метода
}
```

---

Обновление: совсем забыл, надо же по идее сбежать из умирающего потока! Например, в thread pool.

```
static class AsyncHelper
{
    public static ThreadPoolRedirector RedirectToThreadPool()
    {
        return new ThreadPoolRedirector();
    }
}

public struct ThreadPoolRedirector : INotifyCompletion
{
    #region awaiter
    public ThreadPoolRedirector GetAwaiter()
    {
        // combined awaiter and awaitable
        return this;
    }
    #endregion

    #region awaitable
    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get
        {
            // true means execute continuation inline
            return Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread;
        }
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => continuation());
    }

    public void GetResult() { }
    #endregion
}
```

и использовать как

```
using (var t = new DispatcherThread(maxStackSize))
{
    await AsyncHelper.RedirectTo(t.Dispatcher);
    // остаток метода
    await AsyncHelper.RedirectToThreadPool();
}
```

---

Хотя может быть это и не нужно, `InvokeShutdown` не убивает поток *немедленно*. Но тем не менее.

---

Более современная версия `DispatcherThread` — в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541723/10105).

Comment: А как быть для Task? Я не использую Thread.

Comment: @z668: Окей, тогда вам нужен собственный `TaskScheduler`, который будет выполнять `Task` на указанном вами потоке или потоках.

Comment: Благодарю, думаю стоит добавить это в ответ. Пошел ковырять исходники LongRunning.

Comment: @z668: `LongRunning` просто запускает `Task` на thread pool'е.

Comment: Искренне благодарен, данным примером кода вы сэкономили мне ночь без сна.

Comment: @z668: Вот и хорошо :) Не стоит благодарности, информация должна быть свободной!

Comment: @VladD Интересный способ, спасибо! Ваша любовь к таскам безгранична ;D

Comment: @ApInvent: Способ с `await RedirectTo(...)` кажется мне очень изящным, я прожужжал им все уши коллегам. :)

Comment: Только вот увеличить размер стека потока можно только имея full trust-привилегии. Без них лимит - стандартный мегабайт. А вот уменьшить можно всегда.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, в вопросе идёт речь именно об уменьшении. Кроме того, если уж в проекте есть нативный код...

Comment: Эм.. Я как-то не так читаю заголовок темы? "Как правильно _увеличить_ размер стека?"

Comment: @Qwertiy: Почитайте комментарии под вопросом :)

Comment: Ага, уже прочитал. Только, как бы это, эм.. Стек потока - это 1 мегабайт. В x64 каких-либо сильных ограничений на память нет. Так сколько же потоков надо насоздавать, чтобы не влезть в имеющуюся память? Кстати, я не уверен, не потребляет ли поток ещё какие ресурсы помимо памяти под стек, которые сыграют более значительную роль в лимите на число потоков.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вроде ничего особенно большого кроме стека у потока нету. Странно, что x64 упирается в проблему, да.

Comment: А как насчёт хендла потока? У него случайно нет ограничения 65535?

Comment: Не обязательно большого. Возможно, именно лимитированного другими механизмами.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, в вопросе как раз ссылка на http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/29/444912.aspx

Comment: Ну там про 32-битные и лимит в 2000. Кстати, а зачем в том коде `CloseHandle(h);`? Я так понимаю, поток продолжает жить после этого. Т. е. что эта штука вообще должна сделать с потоком?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, `h` — это хэндл, по которому можно дождаться окончания работы потока. Если не закрыть его, то надо хранить где-то и закрыть в конце, иначе будет resource leak.

Comment: Но ведь поток жив. Или только мне кажется странным, что хендл закрывается, а ресурс, к которому он привязан, остаётся существовать?

Comment: Но это же просто хэндл, по которому можно ожидать его окончания. Он не _представляет собой_ поток.