# Создание отдельного потока для каждого объекта Popup

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Суть задачки: написать программу, которая, при нажатии левой стрелочки на клавиатуре, создает выплывающую подсказку с растущей числовой последовательностью (1....50000) в месте, на которое указывает курсор. Главное условие - создание для каждой выплывающей подсказки своего потока, который будет обрабатывать эту подсказку.

Сама проблема состоит в том, что объекты класса `Popup` не отображаются в окне, хотя потоки выполняются. Если кто может указать на ошибки или же подсказать литературу/источник по данной тематике, я буду очень признателен.

Пример кода:

```
//Лист, в который по надобности добавляются потоки
List < Thread > MyThreads = new List < Thread > ();

public void StartPopThread(object obj) {

    Popup temp = new Popup();
    ParamsOfPop FromMain = new ParamsOfPop();
    FromMain = (ParamsOfPop) obj;
    TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
    txt.Background = Brushes.Black;
    txt.Text = "0";
    temp.Child = txt;
    temp.IsOpen = true;
    while (FromMain.currenValue < 50000) {
        temp.Child = txt;
        txt.Text = FromMain.currentValue.ToString();
        FromMain.currentValue++;
        temp.HorizontalOffset = FromMain.x + FromMain.Left;
        temp.VerticalOffset = FromMain.y + FromMain.Top;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    Point MousPos = Mouse.GetPosition(null);

    //создание потока по нажатию левой клавиши
    if (e.Key == Key.Left) {
        MyThreads.Add(new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartPopThread)));
        double a = MousPos.X;
        double b = MousPos.Y;
        ParamsOfPop Send = new ParamsOfPop(a, b, this.Top, this.Left);

        MyThreads[MyThreads.Count - 1].SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        MyThreads[MyThreads.Count - 1].Start(Send);
    }
}

class ParamsOfPop {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double Top;
    public double Left;
    public UInt32 currentValue = 0;

    public ParamsOfPop() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public ParamsOfPop(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
        this.Top = c;
        this.Left = d;
    }

}
```

`StartPopThread` - функция, на основе которой создается поток для обработки объекта `Popup`.
`class ParamsOfPop` - класс, который передает параметры курсора в поток.

Comment: Это учебная задача? Если нет, откуда такое странное требование насчёт отдельных потоков?

Comment: Да, это учебная задача. Без потоков у меня получилось ее реализовать, а во с ними - нет.

Comment: Хм, а где вы показываете Popup? Вы ж его только создали.

Comment: Сама визуализация была написана на WPF. Там вывод осуществлялся через свойство IsOpen

Comment: Хорошо, и что происходит, когда вы устанавливаете `IsOpen`? Покажите эту часть, важна именно она, думаю.

Comment: @VladD в каком смысле показать?
Могу дать ссылку на ресурс MSDN.

Comment: В смысле, покажите код. У вас в вопросе кода, который устанавливает IsOpen, нет.

Comment: @VladD 8 строка тела функции StartPopThread(object obj){}

Comment: А. понял, точно. Туплю. Ну, `Thread.Sleep` — это точно неправильно. Вы ж блокируете поток и не даёте ему отрисоваться. Попробуйте заменить на await Task.Delay(...) (если вы умеете правильно работать с async/await) или `DispatcherTimer`.

Comment: Ах да! Вы ж ещё забыли запустить в новом потоке диспетчер. Понял, сейчас напишу код.

Comment: @VladD Можно, пожалуйста, поподробнее о диспетчере. Что именно я там упустил?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли запустить диспетчер в новом потоке. (В основном потоке за вас его запускает WPF.) Дело в том, что у WPF есть диспетчер, который автоматически запускается для вас фреймворком в основном потоке. А вот в побочных потоках вы должны его сами запустить, и сами завершить.

Диспетчер — это по существу цикл сообщений (message loop), который обрабатывает оконные сообщения и запускает в фоне рисование контролов.

Для запуска диспетчера нужно выполнить `Dispatcher.Run`. Это блокирующая функция, поэтому я добавил в очередь ещё не запущенного диспетчера команду `Work` ещё до запуска диспетчера.

Следующая тонкость — нельзя блокировать поток при помощи `Thread.Sleep`, цикл сообщений должен крутиться, чтобы UI мог перерисоваться. Есть много путей сделать правильно. Например, `DispatcherTimer`. Но самый правильный — `await task.Delay`.

Можно, например, использовать `DispatcherThread` вот [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458425/10105). Вот вам обрезанный до минимума пример:

```
public class DispatcherThread
{
    public DispatcherThread()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var d = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            d.InvokeAsync(Work);
            Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }

    async void Work()
    {
        await Task.Yield(); // подождём, пока диспетчер стартует
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock()
        {
            Background = Brushes.HotPink,
            Foreground = Brushes.Black
        };
        Popup p = new Popup()
        {
            Child = tb, IsOpen = true
            HorizontalOffset = 100, VerticalOffset = 100,
            Placement = PlacementMode.AbsolutePoint
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            tb.Text = "Iteration #" + i;
            await Task.Delay(1000); // неблокирующее ожидание
        }
        // завершаем цикл сообщений, это завершит и вызов Dispatcher.Run,
        // а с ним и весь поток
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пойду менять код.

Comment: @Егор: Пожалуйста! Удачи вам!