# Как правльно произвести вызов события из потока?

Tags: c#

Есть объект А(отправитель события) в нем работает поток, из которого периодически вызывается это событие. Есть объект Б, который подписан на событие и получает данные из объекта А. Когда Б обрабатывает событие, возникает исключение как будто метод класса Б работает в потоке объекта А, это нормально? Пофиксил через SynchronizationContext, но может быть есть получше варианты?

Comment: Объекты в .net никак не привязаны к потокам. Поток не может работать "в объекте". Поток не может принадлежать объекту. Выполнение методов одного объекта в разных потоках - это нормальная ситуация. Поэтому не совсем понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Покажите пример кода.

Comment: Я и не говорил что поток привязан к объекту. Мне показалось что текст, написанный таким образом будет более понятным. Суть в том, что бы из одного потока запустить событие, так, чтобы другой его принимал, не зная о существовании первого.

Comment: тогда SynchronizationContext - правильное решение. можно еще наворотить кода, для автоматического захвата потока, в котором осуществлялась подписка на событие, чтобы механизм работал прозрачно для подписчкика. покажите код, может быть кто-то просто его покрасивее перепишет.

Comment: _"Я и не говорил что поток привязан к объекту"_ -- все контролы "привязаны" к потоку. Т.к. при создании контрола сохранятеся threadid потока. Если обратиться к некоторым методам/свойствам контрола из других потоков, то получим ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

События в .NET доставляются в том же потоке, в котором и производятся. Если вам нужно обрабатывать в другом потоке, есть несколько путей:

1. Смаршаллируйте вызов в нужный контекст ([`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`Control.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), [`SynchronizationContext.Post`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), зависит от типа вашего приложения).

   Пример:

   ```
   void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
       Control.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => OnEventReally(sender, args)));
   }
   ```

   ```
   async void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
       await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => OnEventReally(sender, args));
   }
   ```
2. Перейдите на Reactive Extensions и используйте [`ObserveOn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229634%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

   ```
   Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(sender, "EventName")
             .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
             .Subscribe(ev => { ... });
   ```
3. Перейдите на async-обработчики и доставляйте выполнение в нужный контекст при помощи `RedirectTo`, как описано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458425/10105) (самореклама, да).

   ```
   async void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
       await AsyncHelper.RedirectTo(Dispatcher);
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: в случае с await не получится что в OnEventReally попадет неправильный args [из-за проблемы с замыканиями](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480645/)?

Comment: @Stack: Ну, сам класс `EventArgs` иммутабельный, а если там реально его потомок, то в принципе повторное использование `EventArgs` не одобряется. Сама по себе ссылка `args` протухнуть не может, т. к. в функцию попадает в любом случае её локальная копия. А так — обычные проблемы асинхронного доступа к разделяемому объекту.