# TaskScheduler и балансировка по ядрам для процессов

Tags: c#, tpl

Как известно, TaskScheduler в TPL раскидывает таски по ядрам (хоть и не гарантирует это).

Возьмем другой случай - порождаются много копий процессов, где внутри поток с многочисленными Thread.Sleep. В таком варианте поток намертво прилипнет к какому то ядру.

Вопрос в том, если этот поток переделать на task-модель, то будут ли эти таски перемалываться на разных ядрах или же будут тяготеть к одному и тому же ядру? Хоть это и таски, но по факту один поток разбивается на таски, чтобы избежать sleep и TaskScheduler может тяготеть переиспользовать этот же поток (других то в пуле нет)

Comment: По идее, функция, в которой происходит `await Task.Delay`, вообще не принадлежит никакому потоку. Так что возобновится она в случайном потоке (если вы скажете `ConfigureAwait(false)`).

Comment: @VladD только вот случайных потоков нет. На таски ведь разбивается однопоточный код и пул потоков не будет рождать новых потоков без надобности, а ее не возникнет. Поэтому полагаю, что шедулер будет все время выдавать один и тот же поток из пула...будет ли он рождать новые потоки если увидит, что какое то ядро более  свободно?- вот этого я не знаю

Comment: В моих тестах потоки из thread pool'а тасовались, возвращение шло каждый раз к разному. Но это было на какой-то конкретной версии .NET, у вас может быть и по-другому. Кстати, почему бы не свести все эти процессы в один?

Comment: @VladD Особенности решения. Разбития на процессы не избежать. Возвращение идет обычно к доступному потоку. Более того в Parallel.For основной поток, который вызвал этот метод переиспользуется внутри метода, а не засыпает. В моей же задаче всегда будет доступен один поток - основной (((. Получается что в системе куча ядер, а выполняться будет на том, на котором процесс запустился невзирая на загруженность других ядер.

Comment: Момент, сейчас проэкспериментируем :)

Comment: Вот вам тестовая программа: http://pastebin.com/GKAuY4h4

Comment: Она у меня выдала раз такое: http://pastebin.com/4Dg2ZNy7, раз такое: http://pastebin.com/hwMBTdWM

Comment: @VladD у меня стабильно 1 поток. Значит тяготеет. Вопрос в том, что с этим делать. Не рождать же намеренно потоки, чтобы забивать ими пул в надежде, что он выберет другой. Да и задача стоит не "выбрать другой поток", а выполнить таску на другом ядре, чтобы загрузка ядер не была перекошена из-за прибитых к ним потокам.

Comment: У меня есть решение :) Сейчас найду.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Окей, вам нужно перебрасывать выполнение между ядрами. Это можно сделать вот как.

1. Подсчитываем количество ядер. Это легко: `Environment.ProcessorCount`.
2. Запускаем столько UI-потоков, сколько у нас ядер. Для этого берём код [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458425/10105), и заимствуем из него класс `DispatcherThread`. Каждый из них представляет собой поток, в который можно переключиться при помощи `await AsyncHelper.RedirectTo(t.Dispatcher);` (оттуда же).
3. Нам нужно разбросать эти потоки по ядрам. Это можно сделать как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328752/276994).
4. Теперь в нашей async-функции, если мы хотим поменять ядро, просто пишем

   ```
   currentCore = (currentCore + 1) % Environment.ProcessorCount;
   await AsyncHelper.RedirectTo(threads[currentCore].Dispatcher);
   ```

---

Полный код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace SO5
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<CoreAffineDispatcherThread> threads;
        static int currentCoreNo = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            threads = Enumerable.Range(0, Environment.ProcessorCount)
                                .Select(coreNo => new CoreAffineDispatcherThread(coreNo))
                                .ToList();
            Run().Wait();

            foreach (var t in threads)
                t.Dispose();
        }

        static async Task Run()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);

                currentCoreNo = (currentCoreNo + 1) % Environment.ProcessorCount;
                await AsyncHelper.RedirectTo(threads[currentCoreNo].Dispatcher);

                var t = Thread.CurrentThread;
                Console.WriteLine($"Task reporting from thread {t.ManagedThreadId}," +
                                  $" thread pool: {t.IsThreadPoolThread}");
            }
        }

        public class CoreAffineDispatcherThread : IDisposable
        {
            public Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; private set; }

            Thread thread;

            public CoreAffineDispatcherThread(int coreNumber)
            {
                using (var barrier = new AutoResetEvent(false))
                {
                    thread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                        barrier.Set();
                        Thread.BeginThreadAffinity();

#pragma warning disable 618
                        // The call to BeginThreadAffinity guarantees stable results
                        // for GetCurrentThreadId, so we ignore the obsolete warning
                        int osThreadId = AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();
#pragma warning restore 618

                        // Find the ProcessThread for this thread.
                        ProcessThread thread =
                            Process.GetCurrentProcess()
                                   .Threads.Cast<ProcessThread>()
                                   .Where(t => t.Id == osThreadId)
                                   .Single();
                        // Set the thread's processor affinity
                        var cpuMask = 1 << coreNumber;
                        thread.ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(cpuMask);

                        Dispatcher.Run();

                        Thread.EndThreadAffinity();
                    });

                    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    thread.Start();
                    barrier.WaitOne();
                }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
                if (thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
                    thread.Join();
            }
        }
    }

    static class AsyncHelper
    {
        public static DispatcherRedirector RedirectTo(Dispatcher d)
        {
            return new DispatcherRedirector(d);
        }
    }

    public struct DispatcherRedirector : INotifyCompletion
    {
        public DispatcherRedirector(Dispatcher dispatcher)
        {
            this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
        }

        #region awaiter
        public DispatcherRedirector GetAwaiter()
        {
            // combined awaiter and awaitable
            return this;
        }
        #endregion

        #region awaitable
        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get
            {
                // true means execute continuation inline
                return dispatcher.CheckAccess();
            }
        }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(continuation);
        }

        public void GetResult() { }
        #endregion

        Dispatcher dispatcher;
    }
}
```

При тестовом пробеге выдаёт:

> Task reporting from thread 10, thread pool: False
>   Task reporting from thread 11, thread pool: False
>   Task reporting from thread 12, thread pool: False
>   Task reporting from thread 13, thread pool: False
>   Task reporting from thread 14, thread pool: False
>   Task reporting from thread 15, thread pool: False
>   Task reporting from thread 16, thread pool: False
>   Task reporting from thread 9, thread pool: False
>   Task reporting from thread 10, thread pool: False
>   Task reporting from thread 11, thread pool: False

Comment: Ну  в общем понятно все. Автоматический баланс невозможен, tpl не поможет в плане автоматического распределения нагрузки в зависимости от загруженности ядер. А самому делать такой балансер по счетчикам производительности неудобно.

Comment: @vitidev: Ну, не факт, что автоматический баланс невозможен. Тестовое приложение не создавало никакой нагрузки, вот автоматический балансировщик может быть и вовсе не включался (если балансировка не нужна, выгоднее оставаться на одном потоке, чтобы не сбрасывать кеш процессора). Как простой пример поведёт себя под нагрузкой — надо тестировать. Возможность ручной балансировки и круговой загрузки ядер в примере из ответа.

Comment: currentCore = (currentCore + 1) % 8; очевидно в расчете на 8 ядер, а если их больше или меньше? для меня ответ очевиден, но копипастер будет удивлен =)

Comment: @rdorn: Точно! Исправил, спасибо!

Comment: @VladD А привязаны ли вообще потоки из пула к конкретным ядрам? Я знаю, что однопоточные программы любят занимать одно ядро, из чего и сделал вывод, что поток прибит к ядру...но относится ли это к пулу. Ведь сложно выполнить очередную таску на другом ядре если потоки прибиты к ядрам...ну разве что заранее создавать по пачке потоков на каждое ядро и стараться выбирать поток из соседнего ядра.

Comment: @vitidev: По идее, нет. .NET-потоки вообще имеют право прыгать между нативными потоками (у меня в коде это специально отлючается при помощи `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()`). Скорее всего, ThreadPool старается вытеснить их на другие ядра для лучшей производительности. Но я не знаю, как перекинуть таск с одного на другой поток из пула. (Возможно, если другие ядра сильно нагружены, ThreadPool выбирает ненагруженное ядро самостоятельно.)

Comment: @vitidev: Хм, [документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx) говорит, что на **текущий** момент .NET-thread может менять нативные thread'ы только под SQL Server 2005. Так что это не наш случай. Но всё же, интересно было бы потестировать этот код http://pastebin.com/GKAuY4h4 при нагрузке на какое-нибудь ядро.

Comment: @VladD Я в этой области плаваю, но судя по http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506465/what-is-the-use-of-thread-beginthreadaffinity-method-in-thread-class в CLR 2 наоборот отвязали Thread от физ.потоков оси...и BeginThreadAffinity как раз прибивает Thread к физ потоку оси, а значит ядру. получается изначально managed поток не прибит к ядру?

Comment: @vitidev: Но, документация этого не гарантирует в любом случае. Но вроде бы в текущей имплементации таки-прибит (но это деталь имплементации).