# Как изменить элемент UI запущеный в отдельном потоке в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Консольное приложение выводит текстовую информацию на экран. Требуется дуплицировать текст в окне WPF. Окно создается в отдельном потоке (в том же самом не получается):

```
var loggerThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    var logWindow = new Window
    {
        Title = "Logger",
        Width = 100,
        Height = 100
    };

    var stackPanel = new StackPanel 
    {
        Name = "stackPanel"
    };

    stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock 
    {
        Name = "textBlock", Text = "new text\n"
    });

    logWindow.Content = stackPanel;
    logWindow.ShowDialog();
});

loggerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
loggerThread.IsBackground = true;
loggerThread.Start();
```

Как можно добавлять строки в textBlock из разных классов приложение? Или в общем, как получить доступ к UI элементам внутри отдельного потока loggerThread?

Comment: Кстати, а почему вы не пользуетесь XAML'ом? Это ж не WinForms.

Comment: Просто этот проект изначально является DLL, но в определенные моменты необходимо выводить информацию в Windows окно.

Comment: Ну да, но это ж ничему не противоречит. Создавать контролы вручную сложно и не нужно. А создавать окна в XAML можно где угодно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Очень просто.

**Из вашего UI-потока**, сохраните значение [`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) в глобальное место. (Вы можете ещё воспользоваться [`Dispatcher.FromThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.fromthread(v=vs.110).aspx) из главного потока, но вы должны быть уверены, что диспетчер в UI-потоке уже создан.) Пусть это «глобальное место» называется `dispatcher`.

Теперь вы можете отправлять код в UI-поток, используя `dispatcher.BeginInvoke` или `dispatcher.InvokeAsync`:

```
await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => textBlock.Text = "Всем привет!");
```

---

Кстати, вам скорее всего бы не понадобился дополнительный поток, если бы вы отмаркировали функцию `Main` атрибутом `[STAThread]`. Но при этом для длительных синхронных операций (а такие обычно часто встречаются в консольных программах) вам всё равно понадобился бы фоновый поток.

---

Вот более современная версия `DispatcherThread`:

```
public class DispatcherThread : IDisposable
{
    readonly Dispatcher dispatcher;
    readonly Thread thread;

    static public async Task<DispatcherThread> CreateAsync()
    {
        var waitCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<DispatcherThread>();
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            waitCompletionSource.SetResult(new DispatcherThread());
            Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();

        return await waitCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    private DispatcherThread()
    {
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    }

    public DispatcherOperation Execute(Action a) => dispatcher.InvokeAsync(a);
    public DispatcherOperation<T> Get<T>(Func<T> getter) => dispatcher.InvokeAsync(getter);

    public async Task CloseAsync()
    {
        var waitCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        EventHandler shutdownWatch = (sender, args) => waitCompletionSource.SetResult(0);
        dispatcher.ShutdownFinished += shutdownWatch;
        try
        {
            if (dispatcher.HasShutdownFinished)
                return;
            dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Normal);
            await waitCompletionSource.Task;
        }
        finally
        {
            dispatcher.ShutdownFinished -= shutdownWatch;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        if (thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
            thread.Join();
    }
}
```

Пользоваться просто:

```
DispatcherThread dt = await DispatcherThread.CreateAsync();
Window w = await dt.Get(() =>
{
    var w = new Window() { Height = 100, Width = 100, Content = "hello world" };
    w.Show();
    return w;
});

// ...
await dt.Execute(() => w.Content = "goodbye world");

// ...
await dt.Execute(() => w.Close());
await dt.CloseAsync();
dt.Dispose();
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что в одном из классов, назовем его шина (Bus) в конструкторе я запускаю новый поток, в котором сохраняю в глобальное место диспетчера: dispatcher =  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; и затем в этом же потоке создаю окно. А потом, уже в методе PutInfo(string message); я вызываю dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBlock.Text += message); ?

Comment: @andreikashin: Ну да, так и есть. Код, кстати, можно стащить из этого ответа: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458425/10105 (класс `DispatcherThread`)

Comment: Почему-то не получается сохранить dispatcher глобально. Во время вызова dispatcher.BeginInvoke, dispatcher равен null.

Comment: @andreikashin: А вы уверены, что вы не обращаетесь к диспетчеру до того, как UI-поток стартовал? Поставьте breakpoint и посмотрите.

Comment: я не уверен, что у меня есть UI поток. так как этот класс создается из консольного приложения, а поток запускается в конструкторе этого класса, там же происходит присвоение dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

Comment: @andreikashin: Ну так дождитесь того момента, когда он стартует. Или возьмите `DispatcherThread`, там всё уже сделано.

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит превосходно, но к сожалению этот код не подходит для .NET 3.5 и C# < 6.0. А есть ли какая-то возможность обмениваться сообщениями между потоками?

Comment: @andreikashin: Ох, .NET 3.5... Ну, по идее старая версия `DispatcherThread` ([отсюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458425/10105)), без методов `GetAsync` и `StartNewTask`, должна покатить.