# В чем разница между Task и Thread и когда что лучше использовать?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, tpl

Вроде, они предоставляют схожий функционал.

Answer (score 27):

Это совсем разные вещи.

`Thread` представляет собой физический, системный поток выполнения (за исключением SQL Server под .NET 2.0, да). А `Task` — это штука, которая по сути перепрыгивает из потока в поток, а зачастую и вовсе не находится ни в каком потоке! В результате у вас может быть всего 10 активных потоков, но тысячи `Task`'ов.

Например, если вы делаете `await` на операцию чтения из сети, то он время ожидания прихода ответа от сервера ваша асинхронная функция вовсе не занимает никакого потока, а существует в спящем виде как обыкновенный объект где-то в памяти. Когда ответ реально приходит, функция находит какой-то поток (при обычных условиях это главный поток, но может быть и какой-то посторонний, если вы попросите), и продолжает выполнение на нём дальше.

---

Для текущей версии языка имеет смысл почти всегда предпочитать `Task`'и и избегать `Thread`'ов, они слишком низкоуровневые. Пользуйтесь `Task`'ами, они умеют намного больше.

Мне, например, за последний год пришлось использовать `Thread` только один раз ([вот код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541723/10105)), да и то в качестве дополнительного «хоста» для `Task`'ов. Необходимость была обусловлена тем, что мне нужен был STA apartment, а потоки из пула таковым не обладают.

Comment: Т.е можно сказать, что Task-это более интеллектуальная штука, которая сама знает что и как лучше делать?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Она не сама знает, вся функциональность лежит в Task Parallel Library. И вы управляете всем сами по сути: где и как кого дожидаться, прописано в вашем коде. Просто выглядит легко и просто: `await`.

Comment: А если я знаю количество ядер системы (не важно hypthr или нет, пусть будет 8 ядер) и мне нужно выполнение программы разделить по ядрам. Разве не эффективнее будет выделить, к примеру, 8 потоков (thread) на 8 ядер, которые будут работать независимо друг от друга?  Тут не будет блокировок и проч. оверхеда. А уже внутри каждого потока использовать таски, хоть они и будут по другим ядрам прыгать. Для таких задач Thread очень даже нужен, как по мне.

Comment: @Sleeeper: Ничего не нужно делать вручную, Thread Pool позаботится о распределении загрузки между ядрами. C# — высокоуровневый язык, системно-зависимые подробности в нём решаются автоматически. Ну и с Task'ами вам просто не нужны потоки, потому что в типичном случае большую часть времени ваши `Task`'и не занимают вообще никакого потока.

Comment: @Sleeeper: Thread от блокировок никак не спасёт. Блокировки появляются в результате неправильного управления ресурсами (и объектами в памяти в том числе).

Comment: На своём личном опыте скажу: несколько лет назад я написал парсер выполняющий миллионы а может и миллиарды трудоёмких процессов, и  запросов к миллионам ресурсов на Thread, примерно год назад решил переписать с использованием `async await Task` - переписал отладил - запустил - и производительность упала на 80%. Это говорит о том, что все это параллельное программирование  пригодно не для всех задач, и точно не для работы с `http`-запросами. К примеру у меня пк с двумя процессорами по 36 логических ядер - 72 ядра, чем мне поможет Task ? сколько процессов максимально можно выполнить одновременно

Comment: @DigitalCore: Возможно, вы его готовить не умеете (ц) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491783/10105

Comment: @VladD в этом мире всё возможно, но это вряд ли, на `Thread` я управляю синхронизацией на все 100%, и могу оптимизировать её в нужном мне месте, чего точно не могу сделать на `Task`  как там происходят скрытые процессы, как они распределяют выполнение. В упомянутом выше парсере синхронизируется доступ к 23 `List - Dictionary` и бинарным данным. Когда выполнение процесса доверено `Task` дедлок неизбежен рано, или поздно.

Comment: @DigitalCore: «Когда выполнение процесса доверено Task дедлок неизбежен рано, или поздно.» У меня вот ещё ни разу в жизни не было с Task deadlock'а. Да, есть сценарии, на которых можно по глупости получить дедлок, но это по моему опыту всегда было из серии «не читал документацию» или «не понимаю, что делаю». Например, дожидаться под блокировкой выполнение стороннего кода (популярная причина дедлоков).

Comment: @VladD вы всё верно толкуете,  от меня плюс, просто поверьте за всё нужно платить, и цена Task это производительность, я видел много примеров, и результатов  анализа от самих разработчиков, и даже там жертвуем производительностью.

Answer (score 2):

Я вырос из мира микроконтроллеров. И в этом мире была такая штука как кооперативная ОС. Так вот эти task и await очень похожи на кооперативную ОС.

Comment: Угу, похоже на кооперативную многозадачность.