# Правильное распараллеливание с учетом логических процессоров CPU

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, распараллеливание

К сожалению, понимание `параллельного` программирования и `многопоточности`, как и для многих других ко мне приходит только с опытом. Выполняя некий алгоритм по обработке презентации PowerPoint из 200 слайдов, в `Диспетчер задач - Производительность` я увидел, что мой процессор загружен в среднем на 30-35%.

И я решил заняться распараллеливанием обработки. Дважды продублировал этот файл, чтобы обработку можно было делать тремя потоками, каждый из которых выполнял бы свою часть: первый поток в своей копии файла обрабатывал 1-50 слайды, второй 51-100 слайды, а третий 101-200 слайды.

```
public void ProccessPptx()
{
    Task task1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string presentationPath1 = @"c:\temp200_1.pptx";
        // proccess 1-50 slides
    });

    Task task2 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string presentationPath2 = @"c:\temp200_2.pptx";
        // proccess 51-100 slides
    });

    string presentationPath3 = @"c:\temp200_3.pptx";
    // proccess 101-200 slides

    task1.Wait();
    task2.Wait();
}
```

Производительность увеличилась: при обработке одним потоком уходило 45 секунд, а с использованием вышеприведенного распараллеливания 25 секунд. Загрузка процессора также увеличилась: держалось в среднем на 60-70%, то есть ресурсы расходовались эффективнее.

---

### Вопрос

В `Диспетчер задач - Производительность` у меня следующая картина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и я правильно понимаю, что как не крути и сколько бы я потоков не создавал, то параллельно будут выполняться **только 8 потоков**, а при их количестве больше 8, то они будут выполняться многопоточно, т.е. когда процессор просто будет поочередно переходит от одного к другому?

Comment: Я сделал бы по старинке на реальных `Thread.` чтение с диска возможно в одном потоке, следовательно используем `Lock` запускаем нужное количество потоков в цикле по длине массива файлов. думаю у вас I7 если было 45 секунд , будет 3-5 секунд.

Comment: @DigitalCore,  не все понял. Да у меня i7-8550U :). Ты говоришь, о том что можно не дублировать файлы для параллельной обработки?

Comment: Thread дорогое удовольствие так как при создании нового Thread-а выделяются ресурсы, но одновременно может работать 10 - 1000 Thread-дов, ограничения только в мощности железа. На вашем скрине 4 физических ядра, и 8 логических процессоров, одновременно каждый процессор может выполнять тысячи задач.

Comment: _одновременно каждый процессор может выполнять тысячи задач_ . @DigitalCore, ты уверен? Тут ведь ключевое слово `одновременно` - что оно значит в контексте многопоточности.

Comment: сколько потоков создаётся в `Pool`-е ? может создаваться всего два потока ? или три ? - подумайте над этим.

Comment: Вы правильно понимаете что одновременно может работать только 8, но надо не забывать, что кроме ваших 8 еще есть ОС со своими потоками. Если брать именно поточный подход, то обычно делают кол-во потоков равное n + 1(где n кол-во ядер). Вы понимаете что вы создаете задачи, а не потоки?

Comment: @DigitalCore *одновременно каждый процессор может выполнять тысячи задач* - не путайте человека, не может такого быть.

Comment: @Vasek, да. Но я как-то думал что это одно и тоже (задача и поток). Задача ведь выполняется в отдельном потоке или это не так?

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429129/task-vs-thread-differences?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) не плохо объяснено. Есть еще на [русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548876/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-task-%D0%B8-thread-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Вы не должны пытаться оптимизировать вручную. Создайте много Task’ов на пуле потоков (`Task.Run`), пул потоков сам раскидает их по ядрам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте на обработку каждого слайда сделать Task, а в конце ожидать их выполнения.

```
public void ProcessSlides(IEnumerable<Slide> slides)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach(var slide in slides)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //process slide
        }));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Чтение из файла можно вынести за пределы этого метода и сделать такую же штуку по таску на файл. К сожалению из того, что вы показали, не могу понять, что конкретно вам нужно сделать, но возможно лучше даже вам подойдет Async/Await

Comment: А если в этих задачах идет чтение одного и того же файла, то синхронизацию потоков тоже на себя берет `TPL`?