# Возможно ли включать и выключать асинхронный бесконечный цикл? (C#)

Tags: c#, циклы, асинхронность

Допустим, у меня есть асинхронный метод с бесконечным циклом. Иногда мне нужно, чтобы он работал, а иногда нет. Как можно реализовать включение и выключение этого асинхронного метода с бесконечным циклом?

В идеале было бы сделать отдельную программу и включать/выключать её двумя разными методами, однако не хочется из одной программы делать две

Comment: Если цикл работает, то CancellationToken вам в помощь, с его помощью успешно завершите дальнейшее его выполнение. Если не надо его запускать вовсе, то сделайте некий флаг (bool переменную например) и если она true - выполняем, false - нет. Обычная if/else проверка...

Comment: семафор или awaitable ManualResetEvent позволят остановить цикл на них.

Comment: Э-э-э... Включать/выключать _поток_ это совсем не то же, что включать/выключать _программу_. Вы уж определитесь, что конкретно нужно.

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: Было бы лучше объяснить нам полностью вашу задачу, что вы конкретно делаете, для чего вам цикл асинхронный и так далее.

Comment: Если в примерах, то у меня программа, где я прописываю различные команды, а одна из команд это запустить метод асинхронного бесконечного цикла, который записывает в текстовой файл определенные данные. Я же хотел бы, чтобы этот процесс шёл не вечно, а его можно было бы отключить такой же командой

Comment: Вам предложили два способа - использовать можно любой. Дерзайте.

Answer (score 2):

Имхо, отмена какой-либо задачи должна быть кооперативной операцией.

Для этого существует `CancellationTokenSource`.

Передаем в асинхронный метод `CancellationTokenSource.Token` и вызываем. Проверяем `Token.IsCancellationRequested` на предмет отмены в удобное для нас время. Нас отменяют? Делаем все необходимые действия и вызываем `Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` .

Во внешнем коде дергаем `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`, когда хотим отменить задачу.

Хотим снова запустить наш цикл? Создаем снова нашу задачу с новым токеном отмены.

Это подход лучше `ManualResetEvent` тем, что у нас никакие потоки не засыпают в бесконечном ожидании продолжения работы.

Comment: Потому что ManualResetEvent  не awaitable. Но проблема элементрано решается созданием кастомного с помощью TaskCompletionSource

Comment: Повторный запуск цикла звучит сомнительно. Ведь там могло использоваться множество ресурсов. Следовательно, при отмене потока/задачи нужно сохранить их текущее состояние (а это может быть очень сложно и накладно), чтобы иметь возможность запустить повторно именно в нужном состоянии.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну... это уже зависит от конкретики, которую не указали в вопросе. Может быть там простой метод пинга в цикле крутится, а может и действительно что-то масштабное...

Comment: Это да, дьявол, как обычно, кроется в деталях.

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program {
    private static Task task = new Task(Update);
    private static ManualResetEvent suspend = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        task.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Stop();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Stop();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Update() {
        while (true) {
            suspend.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    private static void Stop() {
        Console.WriteLine("Stop");
        suspend.Reset();
    }
    private static void Start() {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        suspend.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread- это прошлый век. Нет надобности его использовать, когда есть Task.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ты в любой момент можешь предложить свой, более лучший вариант.

Comment: Решение правильное, но лучше использовать `ManualResetEventSlim`.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вас не смущает что Task и Thread это две [разные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548876/В-чем-разница-между-task-и-thread-и-когда-что-лучше-использовать) вещи?

Comment: @Rootware ну Thread-это нативный поток, а Task- это нечто высокоуровневое, но более функциональное => зачем использовать без надобности что-то старое, если есть что-то более новое и удобное?

Comment: @iluxa1810 мой вопрос содержал контекст того, что коль вы перешли на обсуждение не самой сути вопроса, а что предпочтительнее, то есть смысл развернуть свой ответ гораздо шире.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Как написано в книге `Concurrency in C# Cookbook`: **As soon as you type *new Thread()*, it’s over; your project already has
legacy code.** 

Comment: Имхо, комментаторы устроили беспредметный спор. В показанном коде не используется `Thread`, а как раз-таки `Task`. При этом используется _метод_ `Thread.Sleep`, что вполне разумно для имитации пауз в тестовых целях. Если кто-то заикнется насчет `Task.Delay` - ну попробуйте, без введения лишних абстракций и в версии C# не выше 7.0...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Нет. Данный код не исповедует парадигму тасков с его "не блокируй поток, а создай ожидание". Task тут используется только для переброски выполнения в другой поток. Работает как и Thread t = new Thread(...), только с потоком пула. А верность ответа зависит от трактовки автором вопроса его слова "асинхронный", поскольку это более общее понятие, чем парадигма тасков. Но в современном шарпе асинхронность в первую очередь это таски.