# Thread'ы, Task'и, async'и, await'ы в C# под WPF на .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await, task, c#-faq

Начать бы хотел с цитаты `@effetto` с [habr'а](https://qna.habr.com/q/166947)

> Thread (нить, поток) - представляет собой инкапсуляцию потока процессора. Это программная обертка над функционалом вашей системы. Task (задача) - представляет собой единицу работы, которая может быть выполнена параллельно. Использование того или иного инструмента зависит от Ваших задач. Например, если Вам в фоновом режиме надо выполнять операции - Ваш выбор это поток. Если Вам нужно параллельно выполнить вычисления или дождаться выполнения асинхронной операции (например ввода-вывода), то Ваш выбор - задача.

Если верить его словам, то почему нельзя использовать `Task` для выполнения операций в фоновом режиме? Они ведь сами раскидаются по потокам и сделают задачу в фоне и принесут ответ.

Листал дальше и наткнулся на данный пост: [В чем разница между Task и Thread и когда что лучше использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548876/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-task-%D0%B8-thread-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C),
в котором `@VladD` говорит, что

> Thread представляет собой физический, системный поток выполнения (за исключением SQL Server под .NET 2.0, да). А Task — это штука, которая по сути перепрыгивает из потока в поток, а зачастую и вовсе не находится ни в каком потоке!

> Для текущей версии языка имеет смысл почти всегда предпочитать Task'и и избегать Thread'ов, они слишком низкоуровневые. Пользуйтесь Task'ами, они умеют намного больше.

и тут же он говорит

> Ничего не нужно делать вручную, Thread Pool позаботится о распределении загрузки между ядрами. C# — высокоуровневый язык, системно-зависимые подробности в нём решаются автоматически.

Тут у меня возникает диссонанс. Получается `Thread`'ы никак не связаны с ядрами, а нагрузку на ядра раскидает другой механизм.
Тогда зачем необходимы `Thread`'ы, если существует магический `Thread Pool`, который сделает все за тебя, дай только `Task`'ов на обработку. Так к тому же `Tread`'ы ещё и изолированы и от них не получить ответа.

Так ещё `async` и `await` подсели. Что они из себя представляют так и не смог понять. Код с async выглядит как псевдо-многопоточный код, но он, почему-то, выполняется в разных потоках. Не понимаю.

Можете объяснить, пожалуйста, как у себя в голове выстроить иерархию или систему связей, чтобы понять `Thread`'ы, `Task`'и, `async` и `await`?

Вот из-за какой задачи я голову ломаю:
Есть приложение wpf у которого есть интерфейс с отображением ошибок. Есть некоторые циклические функции, которые необходимо делать в фоне. Если в какой-то функции что-то пошло не так, необходимо выплюнуть ошибку в интерфейс и перезапустить циклическую функцию, или запустить другую параллельную функцию, или сделать что угодно.

`Thread` использовал, можно сказать, наобум, как временное решение проблемы многопоточности, когда UI зависал от циклической функции.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyProcessor p = new MyProcessor();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        p.Start();
    }
}

public class MyProcessor
{
    private bool somethingIsWrong;
    private Thread thread = null;
    public void Start()
    {
        Stop();
        thread = new Thread(Loop);
        thread.Start();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        if (thread != null && thread.IsAlive)
        {
            thread.Abort();
            thread = null;
        }
    }
    private void Loop()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (somethingIsWrong)
            {
                Stop();
                // Выплюнуть ошибку родителю (или в главный поток GUI)
            }
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне переписать данный код под возможность `Выплюнуть ошибку родителю`? Использовать `async/await`? Или `Task`?

Можно ли как то использовать `Task` подобным `Thread`'у простым образом? Когда я только про них узнал, сложилось ощущение, что можно, но как только начал копать глубже, оказалось, что вроде бы и нет...

Может быть `Thread` это своеобразные контейнеры для `Task`'ов?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Для начала, есть системные **thread**'ы (я буду их называть *потоками*, ладно?) — это низкоуровневый примитив операционной системы, представляющий собой параллельно выполняющийся код. Потоки операционной системы бегут параллельно, и для общения между собой используют, например, общую память процесса.

Теперь, .NET не даёт прямого доступа к системным потокам*, а определяет свои собственные. Эти потоки обычно строятся на основе системных (это не гарантировано, но в большинстве случаев это так).

Для чего понадобились .NET-овские потоки? Ну например, .NET не обязан бежать на Windows-платформе, и было бы очень неудобно писать кросс-платформенный код, если бы на каждой системе приходилось бы работать с ними по-своему.

В любом случае потоки, как системные, так и .NET-овские, предоставляют очень простую функциональность: запуск данной void-функции параллельно остальной части программы, а также блокирующее ожидание окончания работы этой самой функции.

Зачем такой примитив нужен в .NET? Дело в том, что исторически программисты привыкли работать с потоками, так что не предоставить им эту возможность было бы нехорошо, да и других средств для асинхронности в начале было не так уж и много.

Далее, **thread pool** (пул потоков). Это фича .NET (у Windows для нативных приложений есть свой пул потоков, но реализация .NET под Windows на него не опирается). Он внутри себя содержит набор уже запущенных потоков, и предоставляет функциональность «выполнить данную void-функцию на том потоке, который в данный момент свободен». Если свободных потоков нет, то задание ставится в очередь.**

Для чего он нужен, разве нельзя обойтись потоками? Дело в том, что запуск нового потока (особенно на Windows) — достаточно дорогая операция, а пул позволяет этого избежать.

Далее, **Task**. Это совсем другой логический уровень. Task представляет собой задание, которое когда-либо будет выполнено*** и произведёт значение или выбросит исключение. Каким именно образом выполняется задание, не важно: оно может выполняться в виде функции в другом потоке, оно может нигде не выполняться, а просто ожидать наступления некоторого события (например, прихода данных по сети), оно может одновременно выполняться в нескольких потоках, из которых будут потом собраны результаты — Task может быть каким угодно.

Task**** предоставляет следующую функциональность:

- при завершении задания сообщить о результате или неудаче
- в async-функции дождаться асинхронно выполнения данного Task'а или группы Task'ов, и передать его результат или исключение в точку ожидания
- в обычной, синхронной функции дождаться выполнения Task'а синхронно (впрочем, рекомендуется пользоваться именно async-функциями в этом случае)
- запустить свою (не обязательно void-) функцию как Task на пуле потоков или в новом потоке.
- упаковать другие асинхронные паттерны (IAsyncResult, Begin + completion event, wait handle) в Task
- у Task'ов есть стандартный механизм кооперативного обрыва при помощи CancellationToken'ов
- к Task'у можно присоединить продолжение — другой Task, который будет выполнен по окончанию этого (опционально — при успехе/неудаче/отмене)
- И наконец самое главное — Task'и можно создавать при помощи async-функций, которые позволяют легко конструировать из имеющихся в наличии Task'ов и обыкновенных языковых примитивов наподобие for/while/if другие, намного более сложные Task'и.

Как вы видите, Task'и по возможностям намного богаче потоков.

Теперь, **async/await**. Эти штуки работают следующим образом. Ключевое слово async объявляет как бы функцию, которая производит Task, и может внутри себя асинхронно дожидаться других Task'ов при помощи ключевого слова await. Таким образом мы можем легко комбинировать различные Task'и самыми сложными способами. ([Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/781079/10105) разобран пример.)

Далее, по поводу длинных фоновых заданий. Эти самые задания вам всё равно неплохо бы иметь возможность обслуживать — дождаться, когда они завершатся, получить результат (хотя бы успешно или нет), так что Task тут тоже является естественным выбором. Если ваше длинное задание на деле большую часть времени ничего не делает (а так обычно и бывает), вы не будете во время ожидания занимать ценный поток. Если ваше фоновое задание всё время чем-то занято, то чтобы не занимать надолго поток из пула, можно отправить его на новый поток.

Ну и ваш код в WPF я бы оформил следующим образом.

```cs
class MyProcessor
{
    public Task Work(IProgress<ErrorDescription> progress, CancellationToken ct) =>
        Task.Run(WorkInternal(progress, ct));

    async Task WorkInternal(IProgress<ErrorDescription> progress, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                // что-то делать, для пауз использовать await Task.Delay(..., ct)
            }
            catch (OperationCancelledException ex) when (ex.CancellationToken == ct)
            {
                // всё хорошо, от нас требуют выйти, выходим
                break;
            }
            catch (другие возможные исключения)
            {
                progress.Report(тут информация о том, что пошло не так);
                // восстанавливаемся, чтобы на следующем цикле продолжить
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На стороне WPF вы пишете просто

```cs
CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
Task workTask = myProcessor.Work(
        cts.Token,
        new Progress<ErrorDescription>(errorInfo => { отобразить ошибку в UI }));
```

Callback с errorInfo будет автоматически приходить в нужном потоке.

В конце работы не забудьте остановить асинхронную работу при помощи

```cs
cts.Cancel();
await workTask;
```

---

*Ну окей, даёт, если через P/Invoke, но это низкоуровневое средство для вызова функций OS и других неуправляемых библиотек.

**На самом деле там немного хитрее, пул потоков может создавать дополнительные потоки, если он видит, что у него накопились невыполненные задания, и уничтожать потоки, если они простаивают без работы.

***В других языках такую штуку часто называют [future или promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises).

****Точнее, библиотека TPL и функциональность async/await.

Comment: 1.Лучше ли будет `cts` положить в класс `MyProcessor`, чтобы не приходилось к каждому экземпляру класса отдельно создавать свой токен как предложил @aepot? 2.Этих классов будет несколько (Processor1,Processor2 и т.д.) и они будут в единственном экземпляре на все приложение, стоит ли их превратить в `static` классы по Вашему мнению?

Comment: @Dezigl: Положить cts в MyProcessor, наверное, не лучшая идея, т. к. вы можете хотеть обрывать задания индивидуально. Но в принципе, это уже ваше решение.

Comment: @Dezigl: статические классы, наверное, не лучаhся идея, может быть, имеет смысл, сделать разные методы в `MyProcessor`?

Comment: _вы можете хотеть обрывать задания индивидуально_, то есть?

Comment: _имеет смысл, сделать разные методы_, Просто у меня ведь этих методов будет много и каждый принимает какие то аргументы, необходимые для работы. Сейчас я инициализирую классы, которые содержат потоки и при необходимости включаю, отключаю, меняю данные и перезапускаю. Классы дают удобный интерфейс для взаимодействия с данными Процессорами, как я их обозвал. Можете порекомендовать более удобный 'правильный' вариант?

Comment: @Dezigl: Индивидуально — ну вы можете захотеть запустить одновременно несколько фоновых заданий, верно? Вот и обрывать тогда можно будет каждое в отдельности.

Comment: @Dezigl: Как именно оргзнизовать разбиение на классы — тут нет никакого общего «правильно», каждый случай уникален. Делайте как вам кажется лучше.

Comment: Благодарю за Ваше время и информативность!

Comment: @Dezigl: Буду рад, если помог разобраться

Comment: _В конце работы не забудьте остановить асинхронную работу при помощи_. Я тут поигрался, попробовал не отменять Таску через `cts.Cancel();` при закрытии приложения, но никаких фоновых потоков не остается, Visual Studio говорит, что приложение полностью закрылось. Зачем тогда отменять?

Comment: @Dezigl: Ну примерно по той же причине, по которой вы определяете деструктор / IDisposable. Например, вы можете хотеть оборвать задание пораньше. Или может быть в конце задания вы хотите записать результаты в файл. Или что-нибудь ещё такое.

Comment: Само собой, для обрыва задания я буду использовать `cts.Cancel();`, просто Вы говорите, что при закрытии приложения нужно обрывать задачу, я вот и не понимаю зачем, если она и так из памяти пропадет. UPD: Когда дописал, понял, что Вы под "_В конце работы не забудьте остановить асинхронную работу_" имели в виду обрывать задачу, когда она уже не нужна, а я подумал, что здесь подразумевается момент, когда приложение заканчивает работу в целом.

Answer (score 8):

Постараюсь простыми словами.

`Thread` - Эта штуковина выполняет работу. Вы ей скармливаете код, она его пережевывает. Точно так же как выполняется ваш основной код, в том числе и тот, который у вас создает и запускает новый поток. Вообще любой код выполняется внутри `Thread`, и больше он выполняться нигде не может. То есть это физическая сущность, необходимая для выполнения кода. Штука, когда вы запускаете много потоков, чтобы выполнить как можно больше кода за единицу времени называется **многопоточность**.

`Task` - Эта штуковина дает вам возможность ждать. Чего ждать: например операции ввода-вывода. Например вы отправили TCP запрос и ждёте. Этот код выполняется в каком-то потоке, пока вы ждете? С большой вероятностью и не углубляясь в детали - определенно да. Но этот поток не у вас на компе, а на сервере, а ваш комп ждет, когда прилетит пакет, чтобы отдать вам данные и запустить метод обработки с того места, на котором он остановился, когда вы отправили пакет. Ожидание чего-то, выполняющегося "где-то там", называется **асинхронность**.

Пока вы ждёте может вообще не выполняться ни одного потока, нигде. Например контроллер жесткого диска может искать вам нужный файл, чтобы отдать вам данные, в этом месте процессор может вообще ничего не делать и не выполнять ваш код. Другими словами, для выполнения асинхронной операции может быть использовано от 0 до 100500 потоков. Одна большая асинхронная операция может состоять из много маленьких, для каждой маленькой может быть использовано от 0 до много потоков, и т.д.

При чем ждать можно сразу.

```cs
await MyShinyCoolMethodAsync();
```

А можно не сразу

```cs
Task task = MyShinyCoolMethodAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Оно уже запущено!");
await task;
Console.WriteLine("Оно наконец-то закончилось.");
```

А можно даже ждать сразу кучу запущенных асинронных операций.

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100500; i++);
{
    tasks.Add(MyShinyCoolMethodAsync());
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

И еще много всякого можно. А еще можно (но это не точно) реализовать вот эти 4 строчки кода, написанные выше, но только с потоками (не тяп-ляп, а именно такое же поведение в выбросом исключений, возвращением результатов и прочих прелестей `async`). Навскидку я б накодил строк 500, в лучшем случае, чтобы смастерить подобное на базе голых `Thread`.

Чего еще может ждать `Task` - например когда какой-то код отработает в другом потоке. API библиотеки TPL (Task Parallel Library) предоставляет возможность легко запустить код в другом потоке.

```cs
Task task = Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine($"Привет из потока номер {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
```

То есть, можно догадаться, что этот `Task.Run` внутри себя создает `Thread`, и туда засовывает код. Совершенно верно.

Только создание потока - штука дорогая, жрет ресурсы компа, и чтобы сэкономить, потоки запускают не на каждый вызов метода, а только когда нужно и переиспользуют их. То есть вы запустили 1 метод - создался поток, выполнился код, освободился поток. В когда вы после завершения первого, запускаете второй метод, то под него может быть переиспользован уже созданный ранее поток, если он свободен. Это называется пул потоков.

`Task.Run` по умолчанию использует пул потоков, но можно подкрутить, чтоб не использовал, а спавнил отдельный личный поток, а вы будете вынуждены ~30 миллисекунд подождать, пока это произойдет (то же самое при выполнении `Thread.Start()` происходит, та же задержка). Для сравнения, время доставания свободного потока из пула ~1-2мс. Собственно, плохая производительность многопоточки - основная проблема, которую и решает пул потоков.

Асинхронный код в C# можно писать по-разному, но проще всего с помощью двух ключевых слов `async/await`. Первое создает из метода машину состояний (не буду пережевывать, гуглится тема легко), второе позволяет вам ждать завершения таска и переводит эту самую машину состояний из одного состояния в другое. То есть продолжает выполнение с виду единого целого метода, а на самом деле распиленного на куски в тех местах, где вы использовали `await`.

`await` без `async` использовать в методах не получится. Ну никак не изменить состояние машины состояний, если нет самой машины. `async` без `await` использовать можно, но это бесполезно, и выглядит как если бы вы купили машину, помыли ее, заправили горючим, и никуда не поехали. "Не круто", подумаете вы. Вот и процессор вашего компа будет так же думать, если вы будете использовать `async` без `await`. Поэтому только вместе, и никак иначе.

---

Ваш код, асинхронно.

Сразу уберу код из конструктора, потому что к нему нельзя прикрутить `async`, и перееду в обработчик события `Window.Loaded`.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MyProcessor p = new MyProcessor();
            await p.StartAsync();
        }
        catch (SomethingWentWrongException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Ура! {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Всё сломалось: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

public class MyProcessor
{
    private bool somethingIsWrong;
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        if (cts != null)
            return;

        try
        {
            using (cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                await LoopAsync(cts.Token);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cts = null;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        cts?.Cancel();
    }

    private async Task LoopAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100500, token); // почти все методы умеют принимать токен отмены
            if (somethingIsWrong)
            {
                throw new SomethingWentWrongException("Что-то пошло не так");
            }
            // Do something

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // вместо проверки IsCancellationRequested можно бросать исключение, если отмена
        }
    }
}
```

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).