# Как использовать 100-500 потоков, у каждого свои прокси, свои `DefaultRequestHeaders`?

Tags: c#, httpclient

Комментарии с MSDN:

- `HttpClient` предназначен для однократного создания экземпляра и повторного использования в течение всего жизненного цикла приложения. При создании экземпляра класса `HttpClient` для каждого запроса будет исчерпано количество сокетов, доступных при высоких нагрузках.
- `DefaultRequestHeaders` не следует изменять при наличии необработанных запросов, так как он не является потокобезопасным.

А как тогда быть, если я хочу использовать допустим 100-500-1000 потоков, у каждого свои прокси, свои `DefaultRequestHeaders`

Использовать что то более низкоуровневое ?

Или например, если это будет не бесконечное количество экземпляров `HttpClient`, а контролируемое не более N количества `HttpClient`, то можно использовать ?

Comment: 1 `HttpClient` на 1 проксю - максимум, что вам нужно. 1000 потоков - бессмыслица, сколько у вас суммароно ядер в процессорах? Если например 32, то 32 одновременно работающих потока - оптимально, максимум 64. `int maxThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2` - вот так

Comment: @aepot maxThreads - 64 показывает. Т.е. 64 и не более ? Но я могу использовать 64 экземпляра `HttpClient` ?

Comment: @aepot А 64 Task = 64 Thread ?

Comment: Не 64 экземпляра, а по 1 экземпляру на 1 прокси. И нет, [Task != Thread](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250886/373567), совершенно  разные, не зависящие друг от друга вещи. Если бы у вас не было проксей, то можно было бы вообще 1 экземпляром клиента обойтись.

Comment: @aepot ну мне надо на максимальном количестве прокси работать. Т.е. было бы рационально 1 main поток, 63 прокси = 63 экземпляра HttpClient = 63 Thread ?

Comment: Боже, да вы хоть 5000 экземпляров создайте клиентов с 5000 проксями, но одновременно сможет работать грубо говоря 64. Один отработал, следующий начинает, выбранный хоть даже случайным образом из списка клиент, и так далее.

Comment: @aepot да, уже частично понял) Спасибо! И + читаю вашу статью Task / Thread

Comment: Вам нужно понять важнейшую рекомендацию по таскам: если вы упираетесь в процессор - добавляйте поток, если упираетесь во ввод/вывод - переходите на async. Очевидно, что достаточно в одном потоке ждать базу, удалённый сайт и т.п. Вам надо прекратить создавать бешенное число потоков и умело засыпать при помощи async. PS статья-бонус: https://habr.com/en/post/554214/

Comment: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests). IHttpClientFactory - то, что доктор прописал