# Потоки в Task.Factory

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Можно ли использовать потоки `new Thread(()=> Methods).Start();` внутри `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {...}` ?

Comment: Во-первых `Task.Factory.StartNew` и так запускает поток, во-вторых используйте `Task.Run`, в-третьих ни что не мешает использовать `Task.Run` внутри другого `Task.Run`, в-четвертых - да. Не используйте `new Thread`, используйте потоки из пула - `Task.Run`.

Comment: @aepot, а мне говорили что `Task.Factory,StartNew` вовсе не является потоком, а задачей. Спасибо)

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew()` - это метод, `Task` - это класс. Вам говорили про `Task`. [Почитайте это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250886/373567). Отвечают ли посты по ссылке на ваш вопрос?