# Как правильно должны взаимодействовать объекты?

Tags: c#

Есть допустим сборщик вопросов на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/.

Раз в 30 минут собирает url всех вопросов в список `List<Url>`.

А есть те, кто должны отсмотреть эти вопросы, допустим, 1 вопрос = 1 просмоторщик.

Получить url и перейти по нему.

Вот как у просмоторщиков должно правильно проиcходить взаимодействие с этим списком ?

И что, если список снова обновился (новая версия), а просмоторщики ещё не досмотрели старую.

Comment: Зависит от задачи......... Может это список дел пользователя, тогда этот список вообще может быть у пользователя

Comment: @АлексейШиманский список дел пользователя. Т.е. creator должен впихнуть ему список ? Или же должен быть какой то controller, которому creator передаст список, а controller уже решит какому пользователю выдать. Как это правильно бы выглядело учитывая инкапсуляцию ?

Comment: У меня не хватает воображения, чтобы понять этот вопрос.

Comment: @aepot попробую переформулировать и обновить, дам знать.

Comment: @aepot Переформулировал

Comment: Понял, ответ на этот вопрос - **Producer/Consumer**, и никакие потокобезопасные списки не нужны, берите `System.Threading.Channels.Channel<T>` или старушку `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<T>` и вперёд. Велосипед уже изобрели. Появляется новый "вопрос" - кидается "сборщиком" в коллекцию (канал), первый освободившийся (или рандомный из свободных) "просмотрщик" его заберет. ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278389/373567))

Comment: допустим есть список `List<Url>`, причем тут вообще объекты и кто такие просмотрщики, в каком они виде существуют и как именно просматривают?

Comment: Можете перестать редактировать вопрос, ситуация очевидна, вы забрели не в ту степь, и вопросы именно от того что не тот способ решения выбрали. Выбрасывайте свой список совсем, он не поможет, и перечитайте мой предыдущий коммент, там ссылка на пример.

Comment: @aepot спасибо! Уже изучаю этот подход `Producer/Consumer`. Забрёл от незнания(

Comment: @aepot Это действительно то что мне нужно, получается `Producer` собирает ссылки, `Consumer` их просматривает. А сам `Channel<Url>` должен быть где то вне `Producer` ? И как контролировать нагрузку ? Если `Consumers` не успевают просматривать.

Comment: У вас 3 сущности - продюсеры, канал, консьюмеры. Как их разложить по классам - решайте сами. _как контролировать нагрузку_ - `.CreateBounded`, документация по Channels. Вот еще чтиво https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/

Comment: @aepot Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд это вопрос, относящийся к базе данных.

Начну с последнего

> Этот список должен храниться у создателя или где то отдельно чтобы пользователь не контактировал с создателем ?

список должен храниться в базе данных с полем в котором указан пользователь на которого назначен список

... вопрос полностью обновился)

Но ответ не поменялся, база данных и [entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)

Список хранить так

| creator | viewer | isChecked | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| creator1 | viewer1 | bool | http://anyUrl.com |

Создать классы для cущностей `creator`, `viewer` и `listToView`, и ими оперировать

Comment: Да, обновил xD, извините(