# Оптимизировать работу DNS.GetHostEntry

Tags: c#, сеть, async-await, dns

Пишу программу для сканирования локальной сети. Хочу в коде получать по ip адресу имя хоста. Но процесс довольно емкий, так как запускаю все в одном потоке. Пытался попробовать написать код, который будет запускать метод GetHostName в разных потоках, но так как новичок в асинхронном программировании - у меня не получилось. Помогите оптимизировать работу пожалуйста.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ScriptInfo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UpdateArp();
            string output = CreateProcess("/c arp -a");
            string[] lines = output.Split('\n');
            List<Computer> computerList = new List<Computer>();
            for(int i = 3; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                lines[i] = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(lines[i], @"\s+", " ").Trim();
                string[] sublines = lines[i].Split(' ');
                Computer computer = new Computer(Computer._id);
                computer.IpAddr = sublines[0];
                computer.MacAddr = sublines[1];
                computer.HostName = GetHostName(computer.IpAddr);
                computerList.Add(computer);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine($"Процент выполнения {Convert.ToInt32((double)i / lines.Length * 100)}%");
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine($"Процент выполнения 100%");
            foreach (var computer in computerList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ID: {computer.Id} Имя узла: {computer.HostName} MAC: {computer.MacAddr} IP: {computer.IpAddr}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string CreateProcess(string cmd)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();
            return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }

        private static void UpdateArp()
        {
            List<Task> tps = new List<Task>();
            for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 255; j++)
                {
                    string address = $"10.13.{i}.{j}";
                    tps.Add(InitiatePingAsync(IPAddress.Parse(address)));
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task InitiatePingAsync(IPAddress ip)
        {
            var result = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip);
        }

        private static string GetHostName(string ip)
        {
            try
            {
                var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse(ip));
                return host.HostName;
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Хост неизвестен";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Запускать в разных потоках (точнее - в отдельном потоке от UI) надо операции, которые сильно нагружают процессор. У вас другой случай - операции не нагружают процессор, но операции долгого ввода-вывода. В этом случае рекомендация вендора запускать асинхронно в одном потоке. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250886/373567 почитайте

Comment: Благодарю за ответы