# Несколько вопросов про TPL C#

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl

Сложно понять тему связанную с асинхронностью, потоками и тем, что с этим связанно, собрал несколько вопросов которые меня интересуют на данный момент

1. Как код становится асинхронным и как ОС понимает, что конкретный
   метод надо запустить в отдельном потоке? (возможно, из-за отсутствия знаний вопрос поставлен некорректно, но надеюсь суть понятна). Будет ли чем-то отличаться выполнение асинхронного кода в разных ОС
2. Чем отличается `Task.Run(Action action)` от
   `Task.Factory.New(Action action)`? Что настраивает класс `TaskCreationOptions`
3. Зачем нужен класс `SynchronizationContext`
4. Как вообще работает класс `Task`
5. Что делает `Task.Delay`
6. Зачем нужен `CancellationToken`
7. Какие `непредвиденные` исключения могут ждать меня, если я буду использовать `async/await`?

Comment: Слишком много вопросов в одном.

Comment: @Kotomi вопросы на одну тему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как код становится асинхронным и как ОС понимает, что конкретный метод надо запустить в отдельном потоке? Будет ли чем-то отличаться выполнение асинхронного кода в разных ОС

На низком уровне нет понятия асинхронности как таковой. Есть многопоточность. Старайтесь не путать эти понятия. Многопоточность, это когда процессор выполняет несколько участков кода параллельно. Асинхронность, это когда вы ждете уведомления о завершении какой-либо задачи, выполняющейся где-то там. Чтобы код запустился в отдельном потоке, вы пишете код, который запускает другой код в потоке, все просто. Про разные ОС - будет, но это не точно и нет особого смысла не обращать на это внимание.

> Чем отличается `Task.Run(Action action)` от `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action action)`?

Если на уровне API дотнета, то `Task.Run` возвращает `Task`, который ждет завершения кода, запущенного в потоке. А `Task.Factory.StartNew` возвращает `Task`, который выполняет запуск задачи в потоке, то есть он возвращает `Task<Task>`. Немного разные механизмы, и на мой взгляд, `Task.Run` правильнее и проще.

> Что настраивает класс `TaskCreationOptions`

Это простой `enum`, его содержимое проще всего посмотреть в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=net-5.0).

> Зачем нужен класс `SynchronizationContext`

Когда отрабатывает `await` при возврате из асинхронной операции продолжение выполняется в каком-то потоке. За выбор этого потока и отвечает `SynchronizationContext`.

> Как вообще работает класс `Task`

Он просто ждет то, что в нем выполняется. Как только выполнилось, `Task` изменит свое состояние. Его то и отслеживает `await`. Устройство самого класса весьма сложное и там очень много низкоуровневых штук, в двух словах не рассказать.

> Что делает `Task.Delay`

Возвращает `Task`, который перейдет в состояние "завершен" через указанный промежуток времени. Грубо говоря где-то есть некий поток, в котором крутится код-"планировщик". Этот метод сообщает планировщику, что тот должен вызывать колбэк в определенное время. Вызов этого внутреннего колбэка меняет состояния `Task`, который вернул метод изначально.

> Зачем нужен `CancellationToken`

Грубо говоря, чтобы отменять таски до их завершения. Вы же умеете использовать флаги типа `bool`, чтобы проверить например, повторно метод запущен или нет. `CancellationToken` - тот же флаг, только одноразовый и отчасти за счет этого полностью потокобезопасный.

> Какие непредвиденные исключения могут ждать меня, если я буду использовать `async`/`await`?

Самое непредвиденное - это когда вы ждете исключение, а его все нет, и код не работает, и исключения нет.

---

Можно почитать также:

- [Thread'ы, Task'и, async'и, await'ы в C# под WPF на .NET Framework 4.8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567)

Comment: Что такое потокобезопасность?

Comment: @AlAvenger это уже другой вопрос. Если кратко, то когда несколько потоков работают и не ломают работу друг другу.