# Что происходит с UI потоком async await c#

Tags: c#, wpf, асинхронность, async-await

Что происходит с UI потоком когда код доходит то строки **await** *something_shit*?

Нужно максимально подробное разъяснение или ссылка на ресурс, где я могу с этим ознакомиться самостоятельно

Comment: Ничего не происходит, он продолжает выполнять код, которыей ему поставляет диспетчер. Вообще, с чего вы взяли что await вообще имеет какое-либо отношение к потокам?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567

Comment: @aepot, дубликат?