# Асинхронная пинговалка C#

Tags: c#, сеть, ping

Мне нужно сделать пинговалку на C#, но возник вопрос. У меня огромное кол-во объектов для пингования, примерно 2000, и естественно я их не буду пинговать в 1 потоке и без асинхронности. У пинговалки есть таймер, который запускает метод каждые N секунд, а метод который таймер запустил запускает асинхронный метод через Task.Run. И желательно чтобы созданный поток таймером успел все обработать (если объект оффлайн, то просто пометим оффлайн, поставя таймаут для пинги). Но дело такое, что я сделал всё это, и с помощью класса Ping начал отправлять пакеты (**await ping.SendPingAsync(addr, timeout)**). Но если я это делаю в потоке порожденном таймером, то мы останавливаемся на объекте который оффлайн, и выходим из метода, возвращая поток в пул. Но нужно чтобы поток просто отправлял на все объекты пинг, не останавливая и не ждя, и после всех операций получал ответ (можно какой нить event использовать, например **PingCompleted**). Как это можно сделать?

**Сам метод который всё пингует:**

```
protected async override Task UpdateAsync()
    {
        List<PingObject> pingObjects = await _applicationContext.PingObjects.Where(elem => elem.Enabled).ToListAsync();
        _logger?.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"start ping {pingObjects.Count} objects");
        foreach (var pingObject in pingObjects)
        {
            WaitCallback callback = new WaitCallback(async (args) =>
            {
                using Ping ping = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(IPAddress.Parse(pingObject.Address), 5000);
                _logger?.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"send ping packet to {pingObject.Address}. ID={pingObject.ID}");
                await ReceivePacketAsync(pingObject, reply);
            });

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback);
        }
    }
```

**Собственно класс, где и вызывается UpdateAsync каждые N секунд:**

```
    internal abstract class BasePinger
{
    public int Period { get; set; }

    protected BasePinger(int period)
    {
        Period = period == 0 ? 10000 : period;
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(Period);
        _timer.Elapsed += Update;
    }

    public void Start() => _timer.Start();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Метод который будет вызваться таймером каждые N секунд, в нем идет обработка  
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected abstract Task UpdateAsync();

    protected abstract Task ReceivePacketAsync(PingObject pingObject, PingReply pingReply);

    private void Update(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) => Task.Run(UpdateAsync);

    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
}
```

Вообще вся проблема в том, что объекты моментально могут отвечать, в следствии чего мы порождаем большое кол-во потоков (нагружая тем самым цп). И да, я знаю что ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem берет потоки из пула или порождает их, но я пока не знаю как выкрутится и сделать всё в 1 потоке

Comment: var tasks = pingObjects.Select(elem => new Ping().SendPingAsync(elem.GetAddr(), 500));
var reply = await Task.WhenAll(tasks); есть еще такой вариант, но нагрузка идет тоже неплохая такая по всем ядрам :(

Comment: В комментарии хороший пример кода. Нужно бы его в сам вопрос поместить. Что если добавить `.ConfigureAwait(false)` после `SendPingAsync`?

Comment: Класс `Ping` является `IDisposable`. Не знаю, какие именно ресурсы он использует внутри, но нужно либо диспозить его объекты, либо закешировать их (2000 как никак) и не создавать каждый раз новые.

Comment: Разве при ключевом слове using объект после использования не диспозится?

Comment: Добавил false в ConfigureAwait, но всё же нагрузка на все ядра цп идет в 20-40%, что для обычной пинговлки многовато. А объектов может быть и < 2000, что будет порождать еще большую нагрузку

Comment: Зачем и без того асинхронную операцию засовывать в пул потоков? Вот вам и нагрузка. Нужен воспромзводимый пример. Не вижу возможности рассуждать об оптимизациях на коде, который не могу запустить.

Comment: Вроде,  я могу ошибаться, но при вызове асинхронного метода мы берем поток из пула, и на месте ключевого слова await возвращаем в пул, пока не выполнится операция (будь то вычислительная, или IO), и когда узнаем - берем поток из пула и продолжаем опреацию? Просто мне именно нужно отправить сразу не все объекты пинг, не ожидая прихода пакета

Comment: Например в Linux есть EPOLL, хочется аналог подобного сделать, чтобы у нас был массив объектов, мы просто отправили пакет, и после N кол-во времени снова бежим по нему, и если на объекте есть event (EPOLLIN, EPOLLOUT и т.д) обработать его

Comment: `я могу ошибаться` да

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(Task.Delay(300), Task.Delay(1000));` - сколько времени, по-вашему, будет выполняться этот код?

Comment: Моё суждение выше неверно?

Comment: Т.к мы ждем 2 задачи, 1 на 300 а 2 на 1000, соотвественно 1300мс, но т.к мы после выполнения асинхронной операции берем поток из пула, это может занять еще несколько мс, нет?

Comment: Асихронный метод выполняется синхронно до первого `await`, в правильно собранном методе должен отсутствовать тяжеловесный код в его синхронной части. То есть асинхронная операция может вообще требовать 0 потоков, и ничего там из пула выделяться не будет. Засовывая операцию в пул, вы только увеличиваете на этот пул нагрузку, совершенно без причины. Вот, прочитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567) внимательно, изучите вопрос детально.

Comment: Нет, обе операции будут запущены одновременно, код будет работать 1 секунду. Почитайте ссылку выше, потом напишите мне, прояснилось ли что-то. При обращении ко мне используйте собаку и мой ник @aepot

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое, прочитал. Просто не до конца понимание было :) Прояснилось, спасибо

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него. У вас в профиле есть и другие не принятые ответы, пройдитесь по истории вопросов.

Comment: @aepot, да, удалось, прочитал про семафоры и вообще методы синхронизации. Раньше только знал про мьютексы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Прочитать, как вообще работает с асинхронность - [Thread'ы, Task'и, async'и, await'ы в C# под WPF на .NET Framework 4.8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567)
2. Избавиться от таймера. Если уж вы начали писать асинхронный код, пишите его асинхронным полностью, используйте токены отмены для прерываний операций в случае необходимости - [Создание бесконечно повторяющегося метода в c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1257309/373567)
3. Запускать 20000000000 задач одновременно, даже асинхронных - штука неблагодарная и будет грузить проц даже если асинхронный код написан самым лучшим образом. Так же есть сетевые ограничения, у компа сокетов, чтобы открыть и выполнить сетевые запросы, не так уж много. Я рекомендую одновременно выполнять не более, чем `N * 2` операций, где N - количество ядер процессора - [Массовые асинхронные вызовы с ограничением на количество параллельных без семафора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567), множитель уже подрегулируйте по вкусу при испытаниях кода

Далее, вынести из метода пингования те части, которые не требуют изменения полученных данных.

```
await _applicationContext.PingObjects.Where(elem => elem.Enabled).ToListAsync();
```

Зачем вы каждую секунду повторяете этот запрос? Данные меняются прямо во время выполнения операции? Выполняйте каждую секунду только то, что нужно, а что не нужно - выполняйте 1 раз.

Вот очень простой пример, как асинхронные операции работают без явного выделения потока, одновременно.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
    Console.WriteLine("ping start");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = DummyPing(IPAddress.Parse($"1.2.3.{i + 1}"));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("ping end");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task DummyPing(IPAddress ip)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"pinging {ip}");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"ping ok {ip}");
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
ping start
pinging 1.2.3.1
pinging 1.2.3.2
pinging 1.2.3.3
pinging 1.2.3.4
ping ok 1.2.3.4
ping ok 1.2.3.1
ping ok 1.2.3.3
ping ok 1.2.3.2
ping end
```

Обратите внимание на порядок вывода строк, запуск методов происходит в строго синхронном порядке, а вот завершение - как повезет.