# Подписка на нужный делегат в зависимости от переданного параметра

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Надеюсь, корректно отобразил проблему в заголовке. Дайте знать, если нужно переписать её.

Возник вопрос в правильности моего кода. Суть в том, что у меня существует 2 метода - синхронный и синхронный, который под капотом делит List на несколько и выполняет обработку в нескольких потоках, который задаётся в конструкторе в зависимости от переданных параметров.

```
private delegate Image FaceMethodDelegate(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e);
private FaceMethodDelegate_syncFaceDelegate;
private FaceMethodDelegate_asyncFaceDelegate;

public Image CameraImage { get; private set; }

public DetectFace(MethodChoiceEnum methodType)
{
    _syncFaceDelegate = Device_NewFrame;
    _asyncFaceDelegate = Device_NewFrame_Parallel;

    _device.NewFrame += (sender, e) =>
    {
        CameraImage = methodType is MethodChoiceEnum.Sync
            ? _syncFaceDelegate(sender, e)
            : _asyncFaceDelegate(sender, e);
    };
}
```

Далее через метод Start запускается нужный метод.

```
public void Start() =>
    _device.Start();
```

Используются библиотеки EmguCv + AForge.

Собственно, ещё раз вопрос - является ли корректным данный выбор метода или стоит как-то переписать данных код? Оба метода возвращают Image

UPD:

_syncFaceDelegate:

```
private Image Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var f in facesDetectedNow.First())
    {
        if (**)
        {
            //somecode
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

_asyncFaceDelegate:

```
private Image Device_NewFrame_Parallel(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(facesDetectedNow[0], (f, state) =>
        if (**)
        {
            //somecode
            state.Stop();
        });
}
```

Comment: Этот код вообще работает? А зачем здесь синхронный вообще? Вы точно не путаете асинхронность и многопоточность? Почему вы вызываете асинхронный код без ожидания `await`? Вообще асинхронный делегат должен возвращать не `Image`, а `Task<Image>`, чтобы было вообще возможно его ожидание.

Comment: Да, этот код работает) Не совсем корректно передал то, что выполняется под капотом у этих методов. В sync обычный цикл foreach пробегает по листу. В async - лист делится на несколько и в разных потоках обрабатывается. Да, это не совсем корректное название, т.к. метод не асинхронный, но более близкого названия я не смог подобрать. Можно сказать, что это синхронный метод, внутри которого выполняется цикл в разных потоках.

Comment: Данное разделение было сделано из-за проблемы обработки разного количества данных. В некоторых случаях, данных на вход поступает (количество элементов в листе) достаточно маленькое, поэтому обработать их в одном потоке гораздо быстрее, чем в нескольких. В некоторых случаях, данных довольно-таки много, поэтому разбиение на несколько кусочков и обработка в разных потоках гораздо быстрее

Comment: Исправил момент с формулировкой объяснения сути.

Comment: Да, так и есть, вы путаете асинхронность (anychronous) и многопоточность (concurrent). Чтобы разобраться, надо уловить настоящую разницу. Вот, [почитайте это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567).

Comment: `существует 2 метода - синхронный и синхронный` xD быть может однопоточный и многопоточный?

Comment: Чтобы понять, как привести ваше творение к общему знаменателю, недостаточно кода. Вы же разделили методы, зачем вы это сделали, чем они отличаются на деле? Покажите код.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567 чтобы запустить многопоточный код в одном потоке, достаточно просто воткнуть ему ограничитель на количество задействованных потоков и присвоить этому ограничителю единицу (1 поток) - и готово. То есть вопрос сродни тому "как сделать так цикл, чтобы его тело выполнилось 1 раз"

Comment: Да не, проблемы с этим нет. Просто не совсем корректно сформулировал описание вопроса. Обновил вопрос и добавил кратко внутренности методов, в которых основная суть заключена. Я опустил все лишние подробности, которые-бы мешали чтению кода

Comment: Так вы не ответили, зачем вам вообще сдался вариант с `foreach`?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на вопрос "Массовые асинхронные вызовы...". Я даже как-то пересмотрел подход. Не думал, что так тоже можно делать. Задача, которая стоит передо мной - точь-в-точь, что вы описали в вопросе - "есть N упорядоченных запросов, которые надо выполнить асинхронно с ограничением на количество одновременно выполняемых, и потом достать их из них так же N упорядоченных ответов"

Comment: Ну дерзайте тогда, рад, что помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш способ корректный (при условии, что оба метода и правда возвращают Image), но странный.

Для начала, у вас тут лишние делегаты. Нет никакого смысла в делегате, которому вы присваиваете конкретный метод и больше ничего - проще вызывать этот метод напрямую:

```cs
        CameraImage = methodType is MethodChoiceEnum.Sync
            ? Device_NewFrame(sender, e)
            : Device_NewFrame_Parallel(sender, e);
```

Далее, вы делаете выбор между методами в момент срабатывания события, в то время как критерий-то выбора от события с событию не меняется. А значит, можно сэкономить немного времени процессора если сделать выбор заранее, на моменте подписки:

```cs
   switch (methodType) {
       case MethodChoiceEnum.Sync:
           _device.NewFrame += Device_NewFrame;
           break;

       case MethodChoiceEnum.Parallel:
           _device.NewFrame += Device_NewFrame_Parallel;
           break;
   }
```

---

PS меня настораживает название вашего класса - такое ощущение что вы его сделали там, где было бы достаточно метода. Этот класс мог бы быть частью ViewModel, если бы у него было событие CameraImageChanged или реализация INotifyPropertyChanged, но я их не вижу. Возможно, вы просто выкинули лишние детали чтобы получить MCVE, в таком случае всё в порядке. Но если он и правда такой небольшой, то надо с ним что-то делать.

Если смысл класса лишь в выборе между двумя функциями, то вместо него можно было бы использовать статический метод:

```cs
static FaceMethodDelegate SelectFaceImageProcessor(MethodChoiceEnum methodType) {
   switch (methodType) {
       case MethodChoiceEnum.Sync:
           return Device_NewFrame;

       case MethodChoiceEnum.Parallel:
           return Device_NewFrame_Parallel;

       default:
           throw …;
   }
}
```

Если же смысл класса в том, чтобы быть *однократным* контейнером для CameraImage - его можно заменить на метод, который вернёт Task:

```cs
static async Task<Image> CaptureImageAsync (… device, MethodChoiceEnum methodType) {
   var tcsEventArgs = new TaskCompletionSource<NewFrameEventArgs>();

   SomeEventHandler handler = (o, e) => tcsEventArgs.SetResult(e);
   device.NewImage += handler;
   var eventArgs = await tcsEventArgs;
   device.NewImage -= handler;

   switch (methodType) {
       case MethodChoiceEnum.Sync:
           return Device_NewFrame(eventArgs);

       case MethodChoiceEnum.Parallel:
           return Device_NewFrame_Parallel(eventArgs);

       default:
           throw …;
   }
}
```

Для случая же обновляемого контейнера (который можно уже считать ViewModel) явно нужно событие обновления картинки:

```cs
private Image _cameraImage;
public Image CameraImage { 
  get => _cameraImage;
  private set {
    _cameraImage = value;
    CameraImageChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
public event EventHandler CameraImageChanged;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Изменил выбор на switch, но делегаты всё же оставил. Дело в том, что они нужны для отписки от этих методов. Иного способа отписки от метода я не знаю, поэтому решил добавить делегаты.

Comment: @Frehzy подписка `делегат += метод` отписка `делегат -= метод`, не нужны вам прокси-делегаты, все верно автор ответа говорит.

Comment: На самом деле, вы правы. У меня внутри есть реализация интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged. Я посчитал, что это было-бы излишним, писать данную информацию. Я представил её чуть иначе, чем вы в последнем примере. У меня отдельный  методы, которые я вызываю в свойстве: protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

Comment: Понравился ваш метод SelectFaceImageProcessor. Довольно-таки интересных подход. Обязательно возьму себе на заметку. Спасибо ещё раз за такой подробный ответ. Займусь рефакторингом кода)