# Оптимизация парсинга больших страниц c# httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, .net, парсер, оптимизация

Как обычно скажу что  возможно подобные темы есть. Но я и не нашел, либо гуглил плохо.
Все что нашел испробовал, но мне нужно конкретные подсказки или помощь именно для меня.

Мне нужно оптимизировать вывод страницы, её обработку (например найти слова и записать количество или взять данные со страницы).
Но страница очень большая скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю, возможно для кого то она маленькая, я её обрабатываю за 2 секунды, бывает за 5, или за 10. Но  можно ли быстрее? И вообще оптимизировать **вывод**, и **обработку**.
В дальнейшим я хочу сделать многопоточный режим, т.е парсить несколько сайтов. Но они так-же большие. И не могу понять как мне быстро обрабатывать страницу, или как то получать более малый ответ но данных будет меньше и не смогу все спарсить.

Сейчас у меня есть `List<string>` конкретных слов, я проверяю количество этих слов на данной странице. И как я понимаю такая страница у меня хранится в памяти программы если я записываю её в string.

Вот код:
Консольное приложение.
Главный класс **Program** вызывает конструктор **ServiesCheck** который принимает настройки (В виде коллекции классов 1 класс - настройка).

```
new ServiesCheck(settingslist);
```

Конструктор `ServiesCheck` перебирает настройки (ссылки) и вызывает метод
В конструкторе вызываю метод: `ControlSettingsServies()`

```
    private bool ControllSettingsServies(ServiesSettings setting, CookieContainer containerCookies)
        {

            if (setting.oneChecked)
            {
                var onecheckerservies = OneCheckServies(setting.settingsCheck, containerCookies, setting.linkServis);
                if (onecheckerservies.isValid)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Нашел");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Не нашел");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

**В методе вызываю OneCheckServies(принимает мои заготовленные куки, настройки по которым я буду обрабатывать вывод, и ссылку по которой нужно перейти)**

```
     private (bool isValid, int[] countSearch, string ResHtml) OneCheckServies(ServiesSettingCheck settingsCheck, CookieContainer containercookies, string link)s
        {
            var startTime = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(link);
            request.CookieContainer = containercookies;
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            //request.Proxy = null;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            String setCookieHeader = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

            bool isSerach = false;
            string responceTextHtml = "";
            int[] countSerchList = new int[settingsCheck.worldSerach.Count];

            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                        responceTextHtml += line + "\n";
                        foreach (string worldS in settingsCheck.worldSerach) {
                            if (countSerchList[settingsCheck.worldSerach.IndexOf(worldS)] <= settingsCheck.closeFoundNum) {
                                if (line.Contains(worldS)) {
                                    countSerchList[settingsCheck.worldSerach.IndexOf(worldS)] += 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < countSerchList.Length; i++) {
                if (countSerchList[i] > settingsCheck.closeFoundNum) {
                    isSerach = true;
                }else {
                    isSerach = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            startTime.Stop();
            var resultTime = startTime.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                resultTime.Hours,
                resultTime.Minutes,
                resultTime.Seconds,
                resultTime.Milliseconds));

            var result = (isSerach, countSerchList, responceTextHtml);
            response.Close();
            return result;
        }
```

Код возможно для вас ужасный но по другому не могу, и не знаю.

1. **Как оптимизировать вывод?**
2. **Как оптимизировать поиск?**
3. **И оптимизация памяти если нужно.**
   Или это придельная скорость (от 2 до 10 секунд)?

В дальнейшем мне нужно использовать эту найденную страницу для дальнейших манипуляций.

Comment: Лучше бы сделать код асинхронным, вы можете показать шапку метода и место, откуда он вызывается? Это UI приложение или консоль? Для полноценного ответа нужно видеть чуть больше кода.

Comment: Еще по логике вопрос, в одной строке слово может встречаться только 1 раз? Регистр букв важен или нет?

Comment: Версия дотнета какая именно? Куки точно нужны? Для каждого запроса свои или общие на все запросы?

Comment: stingbuilder используйте для формирования ответа вместо responceTextHtml += line + "\n"; //Записываю

Comment: @aepot - добавил немного больше кода. Нет Ui, простое консольное приложение. 
регистр букв не важен, но я сейчас просто проверяю её через Contains.
Если в одной строке будет встречаться 2 слова, то он каждому слову в массив добавить +1 как нашел.
Т.е в одной строке могут быть и два слова. Делаю проверку через массив (прогоняю слова) и если нашел в строке то зачисляю +1

Comment: Contains показывает, есть ли слово, он не показывает, сколько их.

Comment: @aepot да я знаю. Я проверяю, если оно есть, то я записываю +1 в массив по индексу этого слова.

Comment: Ну, окей, а если веб-страница вообще вся в одну строку? такие бывают. Переносы строк необязательны в HTML. С остальными моими вопросами что?

Comment: @aepot куки точно важны. Одни куки для несколько запросов. Версию что то не знаю, по моему 4.0

Comment: @Konst спасибо за подсказку. Это поможет для скорости или нет? Видел что люди используют это, но не знаю с какой целью. Возможно для удобства

Comment: @aepot оу! Я тогда не знаю что с этим делать. Я просто сейчас предусмотрел вывод страницы по строкам и одновременная запись и одновременно проверка. Что бы потом опять не прогонять загруженную страницу. И боюсь если проверять Contains всю полную страницу то ожидания проверки увеличиться

Comment: Я в будущем буду  ServiesCheck вызывать в других потоках. Правильно или все таки будет не оптимизировано? И на счет асинхронного кода, то я немного не понимаю что это значит. Асинхронно проверки страницы или сам где то код? Где это можно сделать?

Comment: Если хотите производительности, нужен .NET 6. К тому же `HttpWebRequest` устарел очень давно и уже никем не используется. И 2 мегабайта текста можно обработать очень быстро. 2 секунды - это супермедленно, код ваш очень сильно оптимизировать можно. И если это HTML, его надо парсить, смысл вам искать слова в названиях HTML тегов, верно я рассуждаю?

Comment: Спасибо за то что хоть успокоили меня на счет времени. Но что можно сделать в место `HttpWebRequest`? И где сделать код асинхронным? И парсить  я возможно буду использовать `HtmlAgilityPack`, но я думаю это дольше, и поэтому я пока что проверяю, парсить ли эту страницу по конкретным словам, если они есть и количество их больше чем я задумал то в дальнейшем я их парсю. Да, логика такая себе, ведь можно и их парсить для проверки, но я думаю что это будет медленнее

Comment: Я могу написать решение, но позже и только под .NET 6, вместо `HttpWebRequest` буду использовать `HttpClient`, он асинхронный. Для парсинга вполне сгодится `HtmlAgilityPack`, я удивлен, что вы его не используете, там делов 1 цикл и 3 строки кода.

Comment: @aepot спасибо! Я очень рад любой помощи но вот такой тем более!

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы быстро всё работало, надо использовать хорошо оптимизированный .NET 6 и `HttpClient` вместо давно устаревшего `HttpWebRequest`.

Напишу класс парсера на основе `HtmlAgilityPack`. Смысл парсера будет в том, чтобы посчитать количество слов на странице по ссылке и вывести результаты подсчета в консоль.

```
class HttpParser : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;
    private readonly char[] splitChars = new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' };

    public HttpParser(CookieContainer cookies = null, WebProxy proxy = null)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = cookies ?? new CookieContainer(),
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All,
            Proxy = proxy
        };
        client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"); // пример добавления HTTP заголовка по умолчанию
    }
    public async Task<Dictionary<string, int>> ParseLink(string url, int minLength = 1, int maxLength = 30)
    {
        string html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        Dictionary<string, int> words = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        // Descendants - полный список нод документа в виде единого списка
        // из них выбираю только текстовые ноды
        // и зачищаю каждую от эскейп-кодов и HTML-Entity, меня вполне устраивает чистый юникод
        foreach (string nodeText in doc.DocumentNode
            .Descendants()
            .Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
            .Select(n => HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(Regex.Unescape(n.InnerText))))
        {
            // бью текст на слова по пустым местам, можно еще Regex.Split использовать для этого
            // далее фильтрую все что не попадает под мои условия выбора
            foreach (string word in nodeText
                .Split(splitChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(text => text.Trim().ToLower())
                .Where(t => t.Length >= minLength && t.Length <= maxLength))
            {
                // заношу в словарь
                words[word] = words.TryGetValue(word, out int count) ? count + 1 : 1;
            }
        }
        return words;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

И вот так использую

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using HttpParser parser = new HttpParser();
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var words = await parser.ParseLink("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP", 5);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff"));
    foreach (var pair in words.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(20)) // возьму топ-20 слов, чтобы вывод не был огромным
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{pair.Key}] = {pair.Value}");
    }
}
```

Вес страницы 278 килобайт, по данным браузера она загружается за 0.335 секунды.

И вот что у меня получилось

```
00:00:00.387
[править] = 70
[может] = 31
[сервер] = 31
[сообщения] = 22
[только] = 21
[заголовки] = 19
[заголовок] = 19
[ответа] = 19
[также] = 18
[сервера] = 18
[ответ] = 18
[англ.] = 17
[содержимое] = 17
[клиент] = 17
[запрос] = 17
[http/1.1] = 16
[могут] = 15
[запроса] = 15
[используется] = 14
[версия] = 13
```

То есть вся работа по парсингу заняла, грубо говоря, ~50мс. Ну ваша страница намного больше, но я полагаю, что должно все равно меньше, чем за полсекунды отработать.

Из получившегося словаря уже можете выбрать те слова, которые вам надо. Можете конечно модифицировать сам метод и выфильтровывать ненужное еще на этапе выборки. Я просто методику хотел показать.

Можно конечно для получения только текста из документа `doc.DocumentNode.InnerText` использовать, но тогда в выборку не попадут всякие динамические объекты, текст которых может прятаться где-то внутри JavaScript блоков или CSS стилей. еще обработка документа по частям позволяет не создавать больших объектов в оперативе, вследствие чего ее экономить. Но вы можете попробовать убрать внешний `foreach` и заменить `nodeText` на `doc.DocumentNode.InnerText`

Кстати, давайте попробуем

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, int>> ParseLink(string url, int minLength = 1, int maxLength = 30)
{
    string html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    Dictionary<string, int> words = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (string word in HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(Regex.Unescape(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText))
        .Split(splitChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(text => text.Trim().ToLower())
        .Where(t => t.Length >= minLength && t.Length <= maxLength))
    {
        words[word] = words.TryGetValue(word, out int count) ? count + 1 : 1;
    }
    return words;
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
00:00:00.394
[править] = 35
[сервер] = 31
[может] = 30
[сообщения] = 21
[только] = 21
[заголовок] = 19
[ответ] = 18
[заголовки] = 17
[также] = 17
[клиент] = 17
[сервера] = 17
[ответа] = 17
[запрос] = 17
[содержимое] = 16
[могут] = 15
[запроса] = 15
[используется] = 14
[http/1.1] = 14
[основные] = 13
[метод] = 13
```

Немного другие числа, но вы сами решайте, что для вас больше подходит. Мне логически последний вариант больше нравится, да и попроще он.

По поводу создания экземпляров `HttpParser` - на каждый набор кук и на каждую прокси придется создавать свой парсер. Не забывайте созданные экземпляры диспозить, когда они больше не нужны.

Для работы без прокси и без кук на все запросы хватит одного парсера, даже если вы хотите выполнять их многопоточно. Кстати, про многопоточку с асинхронностью можете почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567).

Comment: Сразу скажу спасибо большое. И то что моя скорость отличается от вашей, у меня парсит страницу `wikipedia` - медление. У вас 394, у меня 1.190 - 0.780 (NET 6 CORE) Код намного меньше чем мой. Второй вариант более легкий. Спасибо что потрудились и написали такой код. Но я думаю вы профессионал и для вас не было особых усилий. На счет той страницы то она так и парситься около 2 секунд, или 3. С `HtmlAgilityPack` - буду разбираться. Про  `Dispose` - большое спасибо. Тем не менее буду использовать ваш код. Думаю  оптимизировать такую большую страницу ни как и 2с хорошо.

Comment: @Komend рад, что всё получилось. Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Comment: можете еще уточнить. Лучше ли создавать отдельные потоки Thread/Task, или использовать await/async? Можно ведь через потоки выполнять этот класс. Возможно я не понимаю логику. Или я уже думаю что  разницы особой не будет.

Comment: @Komend не путать асинхронность и многопоточность, две большие разницы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567 В вашем случае параллелить одну страницу нет смысла. Смысл есть только если одновременно надо много страниц парсить.