# Переход из синхронного контекста в асинхронный - что лучше - Task или void?

Tags: c#, async-await

Как лучше перейти из синхронного контекста в асинхронный? Если родительский метод не умеет ничего ожидать, а хочется запустить что-то асинхронно, то чем лучше пользоваться? Вроде пишут что async void это плохая практика, т.к он не дает контроля над таской, запустил - и непонятно что дальше происходит. Но разве когда запускаешь таску из синхронного метода, то разве итог не тот же самый? Он ведь не ждет её, запустил - и забыл.

В общем - задача, запустить из синхронного метода асинхронный, как это сделать наиболее правильно?

```
class Hello
{         
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeVoidMethod();
        SomeTaskMethod();
    }

    async void SomeVoidMethod()
    {

    }

    async Task SomeTaskMethod()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуй в `async-void` выкинуть исключение и посмотри, что будет (`throw new Exception()`). Посмотри так же видео https://youtu.be/lh8cT6qI-nA Должно помочь разобраться вообще в теме асинхронного программирования

Comment: А вообще, старайтесь избегать вызовов асинхронных методов из синхронных. Где-то внизу асинхронный метод - тяните его наверх и с помощью `await` получайте результат. Хотите кинуть какую-то задачу и забыть о ней - сделайте всё равно возвращение Task из метода. Иначе может случится такой прикол: gc.collect пытается вызвать финалайз через 5, 10, 15, 20 или 30 минут и вытаскивает исключение из таски, приложение падает, а ты не понимаешь из-за чего упало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае без разницы, потому что вы не используете `await`, а тот что `Task` - вообще не скомпилируется, и мейн не скомпилируется, вы бы хоть проверяли код перед вставкой в вопрос.

И оба показанных метода являются синхронными. Не `async` делает метод асинхронным, а `await`.

`async void` - это подход "запустил и забыл", то есть вы запускаете асинхронную операцию, которую потом никак не отслеживаете, и если там будет выброшено исключение, то оно в лучшем случае умрет вместе с операцией где-то в пуле потоков, в худшем - обрушит контекст синхронизации, а вы будете гадать, что же на самом деле случилось и как это исключение перехватить.

Поэтому только `await` и только `Task`.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await SomeTaskMethod();
}

static async Task SomeTaskMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("Метод закончил работу.");
}
```

Уберите `await` из мейна и не увидите вывод в консоль. Непредсказуемое поведение кода - всегда плохо.

Если же надо "запустил и забыл" `async void`, то обязательно стоит обрабатывать исключения и учитывать, что метод закончит работу в неподконтрольное вам время. То есть приложение должно как минимум работать дольше, чем этот метод.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeVoidMethod();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async void SomeVoidMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("Метод закончил работу.");
}
```

Уберите `Console.ReadKey()` из мейна и не увидите вывод в консоль. Непредсказуемое поведение кода - ну вы поняли.

А теперь вот так

```
// ПЛОХОЙ КОД
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        SomeVoidMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async void SomeVoidMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Метод дал сбой.");
}
```

Этот метод обрушит вам приложение во время выполнения возможно важного кода. Вдруг мейн что-то пишет на диск, например, сохраняет данные пользователя. Для мейна все идет нормально, но исключение, вызванное в `async void` методе уронит все приложение, и даже если вы его завернете в `try-catch`, это не поможет. Попробуйте поймать исключение не меняя код самого метода - у вас ничего не получится. Кстати, если в этом примере `void` заменить на `Task`, то исключение провалится в бездну, и вы его не увидите вообще, оно просто будет не работать, а вы не будете об этом знать и долго-долго искать причину, в чем дело.

Поэтому перехватывать исключения в `async void` методах - обязательная процедура.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeVoidMethod();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async void SomeVoidMethod()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Метод дал сбой.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Если хочется ловить исключение снаружи метода, используйте `async Task` и `await`.

Что касается

> запустить из синхронного метода асинхронный

то не пишите код в конструкторах классов, пишите его в асинхронных методах.

```
var helper = new HelperClass();
await helper.StartAsync();
```

И не придется запускать асинхронный метод из синхронного. А для обработчиков событий во всяких винформах есть `async void`, и как с ним работать - я показал выше.

Почитать:

- [Thread'ы, Task'и, async'и, await'ы в C# под WPF на .NET Framework 4.8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567)