# Возврат значения из VM Модального (диалогового) окна в основную VM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

Прошу помощи у более знающих, необходимо из `ModalWindow` вернуть значение в `VM`.

Реализация вызова `ModalWindow` в `MainViewModel`:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel(IUserDialogService userDialogService)
    {
        ShowUserDialog = new RelayCommand(async _ => await userDialogService.Show(this));
        UserPage = new RelayCommand(_ => UserPageAction());
    }
    public ICommand ShowUserDialog { get; }
}
```

Метод отвечающий за открытие `ModalWindow`:

```
public Task<int> ShowAsync(object context)
        {
            var coord = MWindowDialogLib.ContentDialogService.Instance.Coordinator;

            var userDialog = new MWindowDialogLib.Dialogs.CustomDialog(new UsersDialogUi());

            var userDialogViewModel = new UserDialogVM(instance =>
            {
                coord.HideMetroDialogAsync(context, userDialog);
            })

            {
                Title = "Поиск"
            };

            userDialog.DataContext = userDialogViewModel;

            return coord.ShowMetroDialogAsync(context, userDialog);
        }
```

`VM ModalWindow`:

```
public class UserDialogVM : MsgViewModel
{
    public UserDialogVM(Action<UserDialogVM> closeHandler)
    {
        this.closeHandler = closeHandler;
        Search = new RelayCommand(_ => SearchUser());
        SelectUser = new RelayCommand(_ => SelectedUser());
    }
    public void SearchUser()
    {
        Users.Clear();
        foreach (var item in context.Users.Where(a => a.SroNumber == searchText))
        {
            Users.Add(item);
        }
    }
    public int SelectedUser()
    {
        selectedId = User.Id;
        closeHandler(this); //закрытие ModalWindow
        return selectedId; //<-хочу получить это значение
    }
}
```

И есть основная `VM`:

```
public class UserVM : PageVM
{
    public void UserAdd(int id) //id - значение из VM ModalWindow
    {
        foreach (var item in Users.Where(a => a.Id == id))
        {
            Users.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно некорректно реализован асинхронный метод `public async Task<int> Show(object context)`.
Так же, полагаю, что необходимо подписаться на событие метода `public int SelectedUser()`, а именно на закрытие модального окна (`closeHandler(this)`). Но вот как это реализовать в коде не могу понять.

Comment: Здесь пара тезисов сгодится 1) если VM управляет слоем View, то у вас нарушен MVVM. 2) если View управляет сторонний сервис, то он и должен отвечать за возврат данных. А вообще метод `Show` же что-то возвращает, почему бы это просто не принять в основной VM?

Comment: А вообще глядя на всё это напрашивается внедрение IoC контейнера.

Comment: "IoC контейнер" - для меня пока слишком будет не понятно, еще все таки учусь и разбираюсь в программировании.
Мне кажется:
1. Я не правильно реализовываю асинхронный метод `Show`
2. В класс `UserVM` я полагаю необходимо передать результат метода `public int SelectedUser()`

Comment: Внес несколько изменений 

в класс `MainViewModel`:
`ShowUserDialog = new RelayCommand(async _ => await userDialogService.ShowAsync(this));`
А также изменил класс `UsersDialogs`

Comment: `(async _ => await userDialogService.ShowAsync(this))` и `(_ => userDialogService.ShowAsync(this))` - одно и то же, при чем второе - оптимизированная версия первого.

Comment: Смысл всех этих шаблонов проектирования в упрощении разработки, а не наоборот. Если вы ставили перед собой цель например сохранения простоты доработок и развития приложения, когда брали в работу MVVM, то и придерживайтесь изначальных целей. MVVM - это инструмент, вы же его не за красивые 4 буквы используете, так? По поводу асинхронности - и то и другое возвращает `Task`, так? Нет? А если нет  то о какой асинхронности речь? `async void` - так себе асинхронность, можно всё приложение так [уронить по неосторожности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1420271/373567).

Comment: К сожалению ваш ответ не помог мне решить данную проблему