# Как получить список имён ветки Gitlab синхронна на c#

Tags: c#, gitlab

У меня есть асинхронный метод получение список веток. Как это можно преобразовать на синхронный?

```
public async void GetListOfBranchesFromGitLabWithAccessToken()

{
    string gitLabApiUrl = "URL  GitLab-сервера";
    string projectId = textBox2.Text; // ID  проекта
    string privateToken = textBox1.Text; // токен доступа
    StreamWriter Branches = new StreamWriter("Branches.txt");
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Private-Token", privateToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"gitLabApiUrl}/api/v4/projects/{projectId}/repository/branches");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string branchesJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
            Branches.WriteLine(branchesJson);
            Branches.Close();
            MessageBox.Show($"Ветки:\n{branchesJson}");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Ошибка branches in repos: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Никак, в этом нет смысла, только хуже сделаете. Я лучше подумал бы на вашем месте "почему я хочу сделать данный код синхронным", а еще подумал бы "правильно написан данный метод", ибо к примеру `HttpClient` должен быть создан только раз и жить все время существования проекта, ну а вы его создаете по каждому вызову метода.

Comment: `async void` не истользуйте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1420271/373567 Ещё открою секрет, `async void` методы не являются асинхронными, так как ничего не возвращают и их невозможно ожидать через `await`. Наличие `async` машины состояний в методе не делает его асинхронным, а всего-лишь дает возможность использовать `await`, то есть асинхронно использовать другие методы. Даже в студии при наведении на метод на асинхронных методах появляется надпись `(awaitable)`, русский аналог её не знаю, но тоже должна быть, у вашего метода такой надписи не будет.