# C# Как правильно остановить и дождаться завершения потоков?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Потоки запускаю вот так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < thread.Value; i++)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => Proc(cts.Token));
    thread.Start();
};
```

Для остановки использую CancellationTokenSource.

```
private void Proc(CancellationToken token)
{
 while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
 {
  Тут основной код работы...
 }
}
```

Как дождаться завершения всех потоков? Добавить их в список?

Comment: если взять такой общий вопрос, то помочь может Task.WaitAll() https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread` - достаточно низкоуровневая сущность. В .NET есть удобный способ дождаться чего-либо - `Task` (задача). Но не путайте с потоком. `Task` предназначен для ожидания завершения чего-то, и [это "что-то" необязательно поток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567).

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[thread.Value];
for (int i = 0; i < thread.Value; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => Proc(cts.Token));
};
```

Подождать можно синхронно

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Можно асинхронно

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

`Task.Run` по сути внутри себя запускает код в том же `Thread` (использует пул потоков для ускорения запуска). Только будьте внимательны, не запускайте огромное количество потоков, это может подвесить приложение или даже всю машину, скорости от этого не добавится.

На практическом опыте выяснено, что количество одновременно работающих потоков оптимально, если равно количеству ядер процессора, умноженному на 2.

```
int maxThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
```

---

Более сложные примеры массового запуска задач можно посмотреть здесь:

- [Массовые асинхронные вызовы с ограничением на количество параллельных без семафора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567)

Comment: С Task всё отлично, но как раз нужно использовать большое кол-во потоков. От 100 например.

Comment: @DropCod3 ну ставьте запуск в очередь, через семафор например. Я же вам дал ссылок. Представьте, что у вас всего 4 лошади и надо отвезти 100 телег с грузом. Как будет лучше, дождаться, когда очередная лошадь вернется и прикрутить к ней следующую телегу, или после каждого метра движения перезапрягать лошадь на следующую телегу? Вот выдав процессору 100 максимально нагруженных потоков, он будет много тратить времени на переключения контекста между потоками, а на полезную работу, соответственно, меньше, это снижает производительность.