# Разница между Thread и Task (async/await)?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, async-await

Вроде я понимаю, что делает и как работает System.Threading.Thread. Но что за класс System.Threading.Task на пару с async/await?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548876/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-task-%D0%B8-thread-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491783/220553

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416086/422180

Comment: Вообще ничего общего, на самом деле. `Thread` умеет выполнять код, а `Task` предназначен для ожидания завершения асинхронной операции. Ссылки на подробности в самом верху, над вопросом.