# В чем смысл TaskCompletionSource<T> и когда его лучше использовать?

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность, tpl

Немного не понял смысла класса `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.
В некоторых источниках пишут, что лучше его возвращать из метода вместо обычного `Task.Run()`.

Разве есть какой-то смысл? Что так, что так я смогу вызвать `await` на вызывающей стороне.

Comment: [When should TaskCompletionSource<T> be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15316613/2881286)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`TaskCompletionSource` — это тот самый крайний случай, когда вы не можете создать «базовый» `Task` стандартными средствами. Давайте я поясню, что я имею в виду.

Если вы создаёте `Task`, обычных путей для этого два.

Во-первых, если ваш код не производит ожидания, а активно работает, например, проводит вычисления (CPU-bound), вы отправляете его на пул потоков при помощи `Task.Run` или его аналогов.

Во-вторых, если вы пользуетесь другими асинхронными операциями, вы создаёте `async`-метод, в котором производите `await` на другие асинхронные операции. .NET предоставляет множество готовых асинхронных операций, например, `NetworkStream.ReadAsync` или там `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`.

Но что делать, если вам нужно *самому* создать примитивную асинхронную операцию, которая не выражается в терминах других, уже готовых асинхронных операций? Как созданы самые внутренние `Task`-методы?

В этом месте вам как раз и пригодится `TaskCompletionSource`.

Например, вы хотите асинхронно дождаться события. Для этого вам нужно превратить событие в `Task`. Это делается как-то так: мы подписываемся на событие, и по его приходу завершаем `Task`.

```
Task<char> WaitInput()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<char>();
    source.InputReceived += (o, args) => tcs.SetResult(args.Input);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Более строгий вариант с отпиской, в которой `TaskCompletionSource` используется как внутренний `Task`, чтобы успеть отписаться после его окончания:

```
async Task<char> WaitInput()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<char>();
    SourceInputHandler handler = (o, args) => tcs.SetResult(args.Input);
    source.InputReceived += handler;
    try
    {
        return await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        source.InputReceived -= handler;
    }
}
```

Ещё один пример из реального кода: запустить и дождаться окончания процесса:

```
Task ExecuteProcess(string path)
{
    var p = new Process() { EnableRaisingEvents = true, StartInfo = { FileName = path } };
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    p.Exited += (sender, args) => { tcs.SetResult(true); p.Dispose(); };
    // запуск выгружаем на пул потоков, потому что он медленный
    Task.Run(() => p.Start());
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Ещё один пример [взят из класса `DispatcherThread`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541723/10105). Нам нужно дождаться, пока поток стартует, и придёт в «рабочее» состояние. Обычно для этого используют `AutoResetEvent`, но блокироваться в ожидании его неохота, и намного проще использовать `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
static public Task<DispatcherThread> CreateAsync()
{
    var waitCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<DispatcherThread>();
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        // тут могут быть любые настройки
        waitCompletionSource.SetResult(new DispatcherThread());
        Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();

    return waitCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Мы видим, что таким образом можно превратить в `Task` по сути любую операцию.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [TPL and Traditional .NET Framework Asynchronous Programming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/tpl-and-traditional-async-programming).

---

Резюме: `TaskCompletionSource` позволяет превратить в `Task` даже ту асинхронную операцию, которая не даёт `await`-абельного интерфейса.

Comment: А если в Task.Run засунуть тот код, который вы пишите лямбде, то не тоже самое будет? А в вызывающем методе await запилить.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Это вы о каком коде?

Comment: Что нам мешает сделать в методе return Task.Run<TResult> внутрь засунуть лямбду, которая оборачивает метод без асинхронной реализации? Разве будет не одно и тоже?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Я всё ещё не понял — вы о котором из примеров?

Comment: В примерах этого нет, я ошибся.

Comment: @iluxa1810: В любом случае, `Task.Run` на неасинхронный код создаёт `Task`, занимающий целый поток (правда, из пула). А мы хотим, чтобы код не занимал никакого потока.

Comment: Т.е грубо говоря, конечный результат и поведение будет одинаковым с той лишь разницей, что в одном случае мы занимаем поток, а в другой нет?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Вы как-то ищете простую логику, а её нет. То, что вы описываете, будет лишь в том простом случае, если вы можете создать ждущий результат поток. А если это event, в каком потоке вы будете его синхронно дожидаться?

Comment: А не проще ли подписаться на событие? И когда оно возникнет выполнить весь код? Возможно, я ошибаюсь, но пока не сталкивался с тем, когда мне этого не хватало...

Comment: @iluxa1810: Теоретически, можно жить и без async/await. Но тогда у вас будет код разбросан по обработчикам событий, и состояние будет в виде глобальных переменных. А об обработке исключений я уже и не говорю — с ней будет совсем тяжко. Но да, как-то люди ж без async/await жили раньше, и в других языках до сих пор живут.

Comment: Хм... А это интересно. Можете дать развернутый ответ вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780882/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-async-await-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8 ?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что когда Вы говорите _“… вы отправляете его на пул потоков при помощи Task.Run”_, то имееться ввиду "вы используете потоки из пула потока"?

Comment: @Adam: Ну да, вроде ж это одно и то же? «Вы используете Task.Run, который в свою очередь использует поток из пула потоков для выполнения вашего кода», как-то так.

Answer (score 10):

На SO был такой вопрос. Почитай [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316613/when-should-taskcompletionsourcet-be-used). Перевод одного из лучших ответов:

В моих опытах `TaskCompletionSource` отлично подходит для переноса старых асинхронных шаблонов в современный шаблон `async/await`.

Самый полезный пример, о котором я могу думать, - это работать с `Socket`. Он имеет старые шаблоны APM и EAP, но не методы `awaitable Task`, которые имеют `TcpListener` и `TcpClient`.

У меня лично есть несколько проблем с классом `NetworkStream` и предпочитаю `raw Socket`. Будучи тем, что мне также нравится шаблон `async/await`, я создал класс расширения `SocketExtender`, который создает несколько методов расширения для `Socket`.

Все эти методы используют `TaskCompletionSource<T>` для обертывания асинхронных вызовов следующим образом:

```
 public static Task<Socket> AcceptAsync(this Socket socket)
 {
    if (socket == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("socket");

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Socket>();

    socket.BeginAccept(asyncResult =>
    {
        try
        {
            var s = asyncResult.AsyncState as Socket;
            var client = s.EndAccept(asyncResult);

            tcs.SetResult(client);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }

    }, socket);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Я передаю `Socket` в методы `BeginAccept`, так что я получаю небольшое повышение производительности от компилятора, не требуя поднять локальный параметр.

Тогда красота всего этого:

```
 var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
 listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 2610));
 listener.Listen(10);

 var client = await listener.AcceptAsync();
```