# Достоинства и недостатки использования async/await при работе с событиями

Tags: c#, .net

В [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780270/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-taskcompletionsourcet-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) теме прозвучала фраза, что работа с событиями по модели async/await имеет множество плюсов нежели традиционный событийных подход-подписался и забыл.

> Теоретически, можно жить и без async/await. Но тогда у вас будет код
>   разбросан по обработчикам событий, и состояние будет в виде глобальных
>   переменных. А об обработке исключений я уже и не говорю — с ней будет
>   совсем тяжко. Но да, как-то люди ж без async/await жили раньше, и в
>   других языках до сих пор живут.

Собственно, меня это заинтересовало.

Хотелось бы получить информацию о всех достоинствах и возможно недостатках с примерами, традиционного подхода и подхода через async/await.

Comment: async/await - более лаконично и изящно, но требует немного перестроить мозг под новую парадигму. Калбеки на эвентах - все в целом просто, но в итоге огроменная куча лапшеобразного кода в котором утонуть не просто легко, а очень легко.

Comment: @Сергей, а где бы почитать? А то впервые про такую штуку в Рихтере увидел, но он говорит, что такая возможность есть не описывая достоинства и все такое.

Comment: Почитайте [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/139734/) и [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh191443(v=vs.120).aspx) дальше гугл вам поможет. Каких то недостатков у async я не знаю - разве что новые способы прострелить себе ноги, но это везде и всегда можно. Это относительно новая и ныне основная парадигма асинхронного программирования у microsoft. Многие языки ее активно перенимают.

Comment: У традиционного подхода меньший расход динам памяти. В большинстве случаев это конечно не критично.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Смотрите. Традиционый метод асинхронной работы — использование callback'ов. В каждой точке, где в async-metode у вас `await`, при традиционном подходе вы должны завершить работу метода, подписавшись на окончание работы асинхронного кода. При этом вы должны где-то сохранить ваше состояние, то есть вы должны при этом таскать с собой локальные переменные вручную. Далее, логика циклов и условий тоже получается размазанной по нескольким кускам кода. Ну и делить на нужные части вам придётся вручную.

Вот пример простого async-кода: копирование потоков.

```
async Task CopyAsync(Stream source, Stream target, CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        var buf = new byte[8192];
        while (true)
        {
            var actuallyRead = await source.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, ct);
            if (actuallyRead == 0)
                return;
            await target.WriteAsync(buf, 0, actuallyRead, ct);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled");
    }
}
```

Ничего особенного нет.

Как нам написать ту же функциональность без синхронного кода, не занимая поток? У нас есть метод `stream.BeginRead`, который должен вернуть объект типа `IAsyncResult`. Попробуем смоделировать нашу функциональность таким же образом.

Для начала, нам нужно где-то хранить буфер, а также рабочие потоки. Для этого нам понадобится класс. Назовём его `StreamCopyWorker`, имея в виду, что логика работы будет тоже внутри него. Затем, мы хотим определить `IAsyncResult`. Объявим его отдельным классом, так как это всё же отдельная сущность.

В `StreamCopyWorker` должны быть методы `BeginCopyAsync` и `EndCopyAsync`. Имплементируем. Получается вот такой крокодил:

```
internal class StreamCopyWorker
{
    internal readonly IAsyncResult Result;
    Stream source;
    Stream target;
    CancellationToken ct;
    ManualResetEventSlim ev = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    AsyncCallback cb;

    public StreamCopyWorker(
        Stream source, Stream target, object state, CancellationToken ct,
        AsyncCallback cb)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
        this.ct = ct;
        this.cb = cb;
        this.Result = new StreamCopyAsyncResult()
        {
            AsyncState = state,
            AsyncWaitHandle = ev.WaitHandle,
            self = this
        };
    }

    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

    internal void BeginAsync()
    {
        source.BeginRead(buf, 0, buf.Length, DoWrite, null);
    }

    internal void EndAsync(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    void DoWrite(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int bytesRead = source.EndRead(ar);
        if (bytesRead == 0 || ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            Finish();
        else
            target.BeginWrite(buf, 0, bytesRead, DoRead, null);
    }

    void DoRead(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        target.EndWrite(ar);
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            Finish();
        else
            BeginAsync();
    }

    void Finish()
    {
        ((StreamCopyAsyncResult)Result).IsCompleted = true;
        ev.Set();
        cb(Result);
    }

    internal class StreamCopyAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
    {
        public bool IsCompleted { get; internal set; }
        public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle { get; internal set; }
        public object AsyncState { get; internal set; }
        public bool CompletedSynchronously => false;
        internal StreamCopyWorker self { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ну и вспомогательные методы для вызова, чтобы спрятать создание класса:

```
IAsyncResult BeginCopyAsync(Stream source, Stream target, object state, CancellationToken ct, AsyncCallback cb)
{
    var worker = new StreamCopyWorker(source, target, state, ct);
    worker.BeginAsync();
    return worker.Result;
}

void EndCopyAsync(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var result = (StreamCopyWorker.StreamCopyAsyncResult)ar;
    var worker = result.self;
    worker.EndAsync(ar);
}
```

Вам всё ещё кажется, что без async/await легко?

С чистой событийной моделью получается спагетти ещё похлеще. Сейчас можно протягивать состояние через замыкания, и это немного упрощает код. Но не слишком. У меня та же задача на чистых событиях выглядит примерно так:

```
var buf = new byte[8192];
ResultCallback cb = (o, args) =>
{
    if (args.IsCancelled)
        Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled");
};
ReadHandler rhandler = null;
rhandler = (o, args) =>
{
    source.ReadFinished -= rhandler;

    if (ct.IsCancelationRequested)
        cb?.Invoke(null, new ResultArgs(isCancelled: true));
    else
    {
        var readBytes = args.ReadBytes;
        if (readBytes == 0)
            cb?.Invoke(null, new ResultArgs(isCancelled: false));
        else
        {
            WriteHandler whandler = null;
            whandler = (o, args) =>
            {
                target.WriteFinished -= whandler;
                if (ct.IsCancelationRequested)
                    cb?.Invoke(null, new ResultArgs(isCancelled: true));
                else
                {
                    source.ReadFinished += rhandler;
                    source.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                }
            };
            target.WriteFinished += whandler;
            target.WriteAsync(buf, 0, readBytes);
        }
    }
};
source.ReadFinished += rhandler;
source.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

(плюс определение `ResultCallback`, `ReadHandler`, `WriteHandler`, `ResultArgs` и т. д.). Наверняка вы видели похожие, только более крупные «пирамиды смерти» в коде на Javascript.

Вы понимаете, что в этом коде творится? Я уже нет.

Comment: А эта устаревшая модель зовется по научному Event-based Asynchronous ?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Это называется [Asynchronous Programming Model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm).

Comment: А про событийную модель что-нибудь напишите, чем она плоха?

Comment: @iluxa1810 её понять сложно, как и что работает, когда логика завязана на событиях

Comment: @iluxa1810: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 18):

Допустим, у нас есть задача для UI приложения: 
выполнить какую то логику, потом показать представление, дождаться, когда это представление будет закрыто и выполнить ещё что то. Как это решалось бы традиционным способом (я использую Window в качестве представления чисто для упрощения примера, в реальной задаче вместо окна может быть что угодно):

```
int i = 0;
void EventBased()
{
    i = DoSmthg();
    var wnd = new Wnd();
    wnd.Closed+=Closed;     
    wnd.Show();
}

void Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Wnd).Closed -= Closed;
    DoSmthgElse(i);
}
```

Обратите внимание на 3 вещи:

1. Логика казалось бы одного метода раскидана по нескольким методам. Это, конечно, можно исправить, назначив обработчик прямо на месте анонимным делегатом, но и там есть свои минусы.
2. EventBased() метод неблокирующий. То есть тот, кто будет вызывать этот метод, не узнает об окончании работы всей логики. Это тоже решается добавлением фрейма в диспетчер или через wnd.ShowDialog() если wnd - окно (хотя это по сути также добавление фрейма), или новым событием, что тоже имеет свои минусы.
3. Мы вынуждены хранить в поле i значение промежуточного результата. Это тоже можно было бы обойти анонимным делегатои, но это привело бы все равно к захвату переменной

Как видите, желая решить казалось бы простую задачу, приходится изворачиваться, чтобы заставить код работать так, как требуется. Но давайте напишем такое окно, с которым работать будет проще:

```
public class Wnd : Window
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> s;

    public Wnd()
    {
        s = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();     
        this.Closed+= (sender, args) => s.SetResult(this);
    }

    public Task ShowAsync()
    {
        this.Show();
        return s.Task;
    }
}
```

Как видно, у окна теперь есть метод, который вернет таск. И этот таск завершится только когда окно будет закрыто. Теперь мы можем переписать вызывающий код следующим образом:

```
async Task AsyncBased()
{
    var i = DoSmthg();
    var wnd = new Wnd();
    await wnd.ShowAsync();
    DoSmthgElse(i);
}
```

Больше нет необходимости шаманить с фреймами или делегатами или ещё с чем-либо.

1. Вся нужная логика сосредоточена в одном методе (мы то знаем, что это не совсем так, но для читателя кода это верно),
2. также вызывающий код может дождаться конца работы логики не прибегая к черной магии
3. Промежуточное состояние выглядит как обычная локальная переменная

Это просто один из простых примеров, что можно жить и без async/await, но использование async/await делает код немного лаконичней и понятней. Вы можете заменить окно чем угодно (получением данных из сети, записью в БД, любым асинхронным вызовом), окно взято чисто для примера работы с `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Особенно тяжко без async/await получаются циклы и локальные переменные во внутренних scope'ах.

Comment: @VladD да, я про сложность работы с состоянием упомянул, просто не хотел грузить автора хардкором :)