# Особенности работы Async/Await

Tags: c#, async-await

У меня есть следующая задача: необходимо в синхронной манере отправить запрос через шину данных и дождаться ответа, после чего вернуть управление вызывающему коду. А могу делать это асинхронно, давая возможность потоку выполнять другую работу. Количество слоев между вызывающим кодом(бизнес-логика) и диспетчером взаимодействия с шиной данных, к примеру, 5. Если я хочу использовать Async/Await, это значит, что на каждом уровне я должен пронести ключевые слова до первого void метода на самом верху. На каждом уровне теперь таск. Вопрос такой: Если в самом низу я реализую ожидание получения ответа через Task.Wait(а не комплишнСорс к примеру, то есть я буду ожидать ответа, блокируя поток), имеет ли какой-нибудь смысл весь этот синтаксический сахар наверху, ведь поток я все-равно заблокирую? Правильно ли я понимаю, что я сам должен побеспокоиться о том, чтобы мой код в самом низу(взаимодействие с шиной данных, жестким диском и пр..) был неблокирующим? В документации написано, что await не блокирует поток, при этом нет никакой доп. информации о том, что мне самому нужно делать соответствующую реализацию и беспокоиться об этом.

Comment: Если вы все равно будете блокировать поток, то смысл возиться с async\await нет. Если вызывающий сверху код хочет дождаться окончания асинхронной операции, то он должен либо как то шаманить с таском (например, вручную налепив ему продолжение или заблочить поток для ожидания), либо должен сам стать асинхронным. Я, например, сейчас делаю подобное - добавляю асинхронщину в старый проект, так у меня все вызовы в стеке до самого верхнего User_Button_Pressed(...) становятся асинхронными.

Comment: Тогда зачем мне использовать Async/Await, если я в самом низу реализую асинхронное ожидание, а вызов метода будет обычным. Зачем по всему стеку проносить?

Comment: Ну вот есть у вас метод `Foo()`, который вызывает внутри себя метод `Bar()`  ===>  `Foo(){ Bar(); }` И где то внутри вызова метода Bar() происходит что то асинхронное. Как метод Foo() узнает, когда асинхронная операция завершилась?

Comment: Он об этом узнает тогда, когда к нему вернется управление. То есть ожидание будет, но неблокирующее, тот же TaskCompetionSource. Снаружи я просто вызываю метод, внутри асинхронно ожидаю, когда верну управление - тогда все и закончится.

Comment: использовать TaskCompetionSource ещё не значит делать что то асинхронно или неблокирующе. Если метод Foo() вызвал метод Bar() и ждет его завершения, пока происходит асинхронная операция, то поток, в котором происходит ожидание, заблокирован, не зависимо от того, используете вы TaskCompetionSource или нет.

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, почему? TaskCompetionSource согласно документации представляет неблокирующее замораживание таска. У меня по сути два вопроса: 1 - почему TaskCompetionSource будет блокировать поток, а 2 - каким образом async/await делает TaskCompetionSource  неблокирующим?

Comment: Вам нужно понять принцип работы асинхронной операции. Например, вот тут `async Task Foo(){ await Bar(); }` ожидания потока не происходит, так как метод Foo() может быть вызван в одном потоке, а закончен в другом. Однако, если вызывать асинхронный `Bar` синхронно - вот так `Foo(){ Bar(); }` , то функция Foo() закончит выполнение ДО завершения асинхронной операции `Bar`. А если вызывать вот так: `Foo(){ Bar().Wait(); }` то поток, когда начнет выполнение функции Foo, станет ждать окончания функции Bar - ключевое слово **ждать**, то есть будет заблокирован.

Comment: То есть я буду использовать  Bar().Wait() в рамках async/await, то поток не будет заблокирован, а если без async/await, то будет? Каким образом async/await делает такую магию? Я знаю, что захватывается контекст синхронизации, строится машина состояния, но все же механика не ясна.

Comment: Bar().Wait() - это всегда блокировка потока. Асинхронная операция, грубо говоря, это какой то абстрактный Task - не важно, как этот таск был создан. Важно, что это таск - то есть что то, что выполняется, что когда то-кончится и у чего может быть возвращаемый результат. Поэтому все асинхронные функции возвращают таск - так какпо завершении функции завершается таск, который они возвращают.  Например, для асинхронного Bar() можно написать var task = Bar(); - но это не означает, что асинхронная функция Bar() после этой строчки завершена. Асинхронная функция будет завершена, когда завершится таск.

Comment: В общем, из меня тот ещё учитель. Почитайте вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-async-await-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD) - надеюсь станет яснее.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения. Вопросы пока еще остаются, но становится понятнее. Я не улавливаю одного: как мне дождаться ответа из шины данных, не блоуируя поток. То есть сам по себе await ничего не гарантирует, но, как я понимаю, если внутри для ождиания использоватьTaskCompletionSource, а наверху над этим всем async/await, то будет профит. Или нет? Как сам по себе await может ждать того, чего не знает как получить. Механизм ожидания я реализую сам и там нет готовых readAsync или чего-то подобного.

Comment: Вот [пример с окном](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/781007/179763) - там по сути создается таск (с использованием TaskCompletionSource), который завершается, когда окно закрывается. Вам нужно по сути то же, только вместо открытия окна - отправка сообщения, вместо закрытия - получение сообщения. При этом все вверх по стеку станет асинхронным (все, что хочет дождаться завершения таска). То есть переписать код, чтобы не блокировать поток в вашем случае можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать асинхронность имеет смысл в тех случаях, когда задача по своей природе - асинхронна. В таких случаях вам в любом случае придется обеспечивать синхронизацию с остальным кодом, и механизм задач тут - довольно простой вариант.

Если же на самом низком уровне все синхронно - то нет никакого смысла делать все асинхронным.

Иными словами, пляшите от кода низкого уровня, как вам удобнее его писать. А на верхнем уровне просто используйте то, что написано на нижнем. Ну и не забывайте про требования к быстродействию - в том случае когда нижний уровень предоставляет несколько вариантов API.

---

Рассмотрим ваш пример с шиной. Шина данных (если вы имеете в виду интеграционную шину) может работать несколькими способами. Самый простой из них - синхронные запросы по некоторому протоколу - вы просто делаете запрос и получаете ответ. Если это происходит по HTTP или TCP - то в стандартной библиотеке есть оба варианта API - синхронной и асинхронный. Нужно выбирать тот, который отвечает требованиям по быстродействию. Если у вас одновременно идут сотни или тысячи исходящих запросов - нужно использовать асинхронный вариант (и, конечно же, никаких блокировок на верхнем уровне!). Если вы делаете все запросы последовательно - то синхронного варианта вполне достаточно.

Но у вас упомянут какой-то диспетчер взаимодействия с шиной, значит все не так просто. Значит, шина возвращает ответы на запросы асинхронно и вперемешку, и вам необходимо их прослушивать в отдельном потоке. В таком случае у задачи очевидно асинхронная природа - и вам **в любом случае нужна синхронизация**. И `TaskCompletionSource` дает ее близким к оптимальному способом; странно его не использовать:

```
public Task<Response> SendRequestAsync (Request req)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    lock(requests) requests.Add(request.Id, tcs);
    // ...
    return tcs.Task;
}

public Response SendRequest (Request req) => SendRequestAsync(req).Result;

private void OnResponse(Response resp) 
{
    lock(requests)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Response> tcs;
        if (requests.TryGetValue(resp.RequestId, out tcs))
        {
            requests.Remove(resp.RequestId);
            tcs.SetResult(resp);
        }
    }
}
```

И нет никаких проблем с синхронным ожиданием через `.Wait()` или `.Result` если это необходимо (главное - следите [в каком потоке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514529/178779) вы это делаете).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!. Интеграционная шина данных, которую я упомянул, работает последовательно и гарантирует правильный порядок прихода данных. Шина IBM. Мне по сути нужно что-то положить в очередь, далее - ожидать прихода ответа. TaskCompletionSource, как я понимаю, как раз и нужно использовать для имитации этого ожидания. Но причем тогда тут async/await?

Comment: @Sleeeper при том что async/await - это удобный способ работы с асинхронными задачами асинхронно же

Comment: @Sleeeper кстати, не рассчитывайте на правильный порядок прихода ответов если делаете запросы к разным получателям

Comment: Спасибо. То есть, насколько я понимаю, в рамках решаемой задачи поток будет блокироваться так или иначе, но TaskCompletionSource самый оптимальный вариант. Async/Await нужен тут лишь для того, чтобы на верхнем уровне писать в синхронном стиле. Сам по себе await никакой магии не делает.

Comment: @Sleeeper нет. Если вы протянете Async/Await до самого верхнего уровня - ваш **основной** поток блокироваться перестанет.

Comment: Хорошо. Для проведения сравнения. Будет ли блокирован поток, в случае использования на низком уровне вместо TaskCompletionSource  обычного Task(Wait) и пронесения  Async/Await по всему стеку? Или же это неблокирование связано с тем, что вместе с Async/Await  используется именно TaskCompletionSource? Извините за излишнюю детализацию.

Comment: @Sleeeper что такое *"обычный Task(Wait) вместо TaskCompletionSource"*?

Comment: Для ожидания использовать Task.Wait, вместо TaskCompletionSource.Wait (SetResult)

Comment: @Sleeeper у TaskCompletionSource нет метода Wait.

Comment: Да,я понял. Над TaskCompletionSource можно сделать только await. Поток блокирован не будет. Когда придет ответ из шины, я делаю SetResult, работа продолжается в том же контексте (или в другом, если понадобится).

Comment: @Sleeeper await над TaskCompletionSource тоже не сделать

Comment: Не очень понимаю. Я ведь могу сделать await taslCompetionSource.Task ?

Comment: @Sleeeper ну так вы и `tsc.Task.Wait()` сделать можете. Только это уже метод Task получается, а не метод TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: Видимо я не очень корректно объяснил задачу. У меня есть некоторый контекст , в рамках которого выполняется запрос и ожидание ответа из шины.  Так вот я не могу просто положить что-то в очередь и продолжить работу, мне нужно еще дождаться ответа, причем это должно выглядеть синхронным, но поток не блокировать. В Вашем примере в случае  SendRequestAsync вы вернете управление вызывающему коду, а мне же нужно тут же дождаться ответа.

Comment: @Sleeeper так не бывает. Вы либо возвращаете управление вызывающему коду - либо блокируете поток, третьего не дано. Это антонимы.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде разобрался.