# Для чего использовать async/await в CPU bound операциях?

Tags: c#, async-await

Допустим, мы разрабатываем программу с графическим интерфейсом и наша задача не допустить "заморозки" UI. В случае с I/O bound операциями все понятно. Использовать для таких операций отдельный поток для ожидания, например, ответа от сервера дорого, лучше воспользоваться async/await. Но для чего же использовать async/await в CPU bound операциях? Ведь нам в любом случае придется использовать дополнительный поток для вычислений. Я что-то упускаю?

Comment: `DoJob()` занимает текущий поток, `await Task.Run(() => DoJob())` - не занимает, а берет поток из пула и занимает его. Главный плюс в том, что первый случай синхронный, можно выполнять одновременно только одну операцию, второй случай позволяет выполнять одновременно 100500 операций (технически до `int.MaxValue` потоков).

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы хотите узнать, что CPU-bound операция завершилась. Если вам надо просто её запустить и забыть, то подойдет что угодно, например, вы можете напрямую обратиться в пул потоков и добавить туда задачу. Если вам надо асинхронно ожидать - то async/await.

Comment: На самом деле применение async/await не ограничивается I/O операциями, есть и другие варианты использования. Например, [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/781007/179763)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

async/await это всего лишь синтаксический сахара, который позволяет писать более понятный и читаемый код. В том числе он реализует синхронизацию контекстов, если в вызывающем потоке задан контекст синхронизации. То есть код после вызова и выполнения awit метода продолжит выполняться в том же потоке что и до вызова. В данном случае UI потоке. Если отключить эту логику, то продолжение может выполнятся на любом из доступных потоков из пула, что чревато доступом к UI элементам из другого (не UI) потока. Что может приводить к различным ошибкам. До появления async/await задача доступа из другого потока решалась вызовом BeginInvoke или с использованием типа BackgroundWorker.

Теперь про применимость c CPU bound операциями.
Такие операции также могут занимать значительное время. К примеру просчеты каких-либо математических моделей или сложных, циклических вычислений. Чтобы при этом ваш GUI остался отзывчивым необходимо не занимать UI поток этими вычислениями. Вы можете вынести такую логику в отдельный метод.

```
public Task<long> Calculate(...)
{
    return Task.Run(
       ....
    );
}
```

И вызывать его в GUI с использованием await, не переживая за синхронизацию потоков после получения ответа. Ваш GUI не сломается и будет доступен, так как вычисления будут происходить в отдельном потоке из пула.

Логику по синхронизации можно выключить используя `.ConfigureAwait(false)`