# Что такое асинхронная функция/метод в C# и программировании в целом?

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Что именно стоит называть асинхронным методом? Какой критерий должен быть что бы назвать метод асинхронным? Другая терминология вроде понятна, но давайте повторим ее что бы дальше использовать в попытках опеределить понятие асинхронного метода.

### Вспоминаем связанные понятия

Есть понятие Asynchronous method invocation ([AMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_method_invocation)) -

> call site is not blocked while waiting for the called code to finish.
> Instead, the calling thread is notified when the reply arrives.

причем слово invocation могут менять на call или execution.

Есть понятие асинхронность, но в программировании похоже его используют с AMI почти взаимозаменяемо ([1](https://habr.com/ru/post/452094/)) -

> выполнение операции без ожидания окончания завершения этой обработки,
> результат же выполнения может быть обработан позднее.

Часто приводят пример с чайником который ставят кипятить, для того что бы обьяснить что это такое.

### Давайте искать определение для асинхронного метода, и на время забудем то как мы себе это представляли для того что бы быть обьективными.

1. Источник первый - документация к ключевому слову [async](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) -

> Use the async modifier to specify that a method, lambda expression,
> or anonymous method is asynchronous. **If you use this modifier on a
> method or expression, it's referred to as an async method**.

Что можно перевести как: Если вы используете этот модификатор в методе или выражении, он называется асинхронным методом. **Понятно что не каждый метод с async обязательно в реальности содержит AMI или что-то связанное с асинхронностью.**

2. С другой стороны есть такой источник [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083613/what-does-it-mean-for-a-method-to-be-asynchronous):

> An asynchronous method is one that we call to start the lengthy
> operation. The method should do what it needs to start the operation
> and return "very quickly" so that there are no processing delays.

> A method is asynchronous if your thread tells the method that it needs
> the work to be done, and the method says "OK, I'll do that and I'll
> call you when it is finished"

Это намекает нам на то что в опеделении асинхронного метода должно быть что то про AMI, который мы вспоминали выше.

3. Еще у того же микрософта в старой доке (до появления ключевого слова async) можно встретить следующее использование этого термина ([3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2004/january/basic-instincts-asynchronous-method-execution-using-delegates)):

> If the asynchronous method experiences an unhandled exception,...

Значит вроде как такое понятие было еще до ключевого слова async, но возможно с его появление появились новые смыслы связанные чисто с синтаксисом языка.

4. ...

К сожалению изучать источники дело долгое, поэтому даю возможность дополнить тем кто будет отвечать на вопрос.

### Пробуем по источникам дать определение

Какие варианты определения асинхронного метода приходят в голову исходя из изученных источников:

1. это метод с ключевым словом async при обьявлении. Пример:

```
async void SimpleAsync() {}
```

2. это метод, который можно использовать для не блокирующего вызова. Пример:

```
async void DelayAsync() { Task.Delay(1); } //Task.Delay асинхронный, так его можно использовать для AMI. Прям тут и используют.  
async void Delay2Async() { await Task.Delay(1); } //Task.Delay асинхронный, так его можно использовать для AMI. Прям тут и используют.
async Task Delay3Async() { await Task.Delay(1); } //Task.Delay асинхронный, так его можно использовать для AMI. Прям тут и используют. 


async void DelayExternalAsync() { DelayAsync(); Delay2Async(); } //DelayAsync и Delay2Async асинхронные, так их можно использовать для AMI. Прям тут и используют.
async void DelayExternalAwaitAsync() { await Delay3Async(); } //Delay3Async асинхронный, так его можно использовать для AMI. Прям тут и используют.
//DelayExternalAsync и DelayExternalAwaitAsync асинхронные, так их можно использовать для AMI. Хотя тут их не используют для этого.

async Task<int> JustEmptyAsync() { return await Task.FromResult(1); } // JustEmptyAsync не асинхронный, так его не можно использовать для AMI в других местах, так как внутри ничего асинхронного.
```

3. это метод в котором происходит не блокирующий вызов. В примере почти все методы асинхронные, но не Task.Delay, так как в нем самом AMI нет, по крайней мере смотря на имеющийся код (может это и не так, но можем на время сделать такое допущение. Хотя тут тоже вопрос - существуют ли такие методы, которые могут быть вызваны не блокирующе, но сами не содержат AMI? Если да, то именно такой метод и хотелось бы тут использовать для примера, иначе этот вариант похоже эквивалентен второму):

```
async void DelayAsync() { Task.Delay(1); } //DelayAsync асинхронный, так как в нем есть AMI 
async void Delay2Async() { await Task.Delay(1); } //Delay2Async асинхронный, так как в нем есть AMI 
async Task Delay3Async() { await Task.Delay(1); } //Delay3Async асинхронный, так как в нем есть AMI 


async void DelayExternalAsync() { DelayAsync(); } //DelayExternalAsync асинхронный, так как в нем есть AMI 
async void DelayExternalAwaitAsync() { await Delay3Async(); } //DelayExternalAwaitAsync асинхронный, так как в нем есть AMI
```

4. Другие варианты...

### Подчеркнем первоначальный вопрос и дополним его тем что узнали в ходе изучения источников

Какой первоисточник этого понятия? Какое значение оно имеет сейчас? Или это как и многие другие термины в которые на слуху но четкого определения не имеют - кто как хочет так и понимает? Есть несколько определений, которые накопились со временем?

Comment: Могу в примерах не правильно использовать определение AMI, тогда поправляйте...

Comment: [Многопоточное vs асинхронное программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445768/179763)

Comment: Немного отрефакторил сам вопрос что бы расставить акценты.

Comment: Как видно, вы не приняли ни одного ответа, следовательно вамс они не устраивают. Свой ответ я удалю, так как очевидно, не попал в ваши ожидания, вопрос переоткрыл.

Comment: @aepot, жаль, я бы вам еще столько уточнений задал по вашему ответу :) В дополнение он давал понимание асинхронной операции, отличать эти понятия всем тоже было бы полезно. Сразу выбрать один ответ лучшим - не мой подход, думаю это уберет мотивацию у других писать свой ответ. Тем более каждый ответ должен выдержать испытание временем, моими вопросами и вопросами публики, это как выдержанное вино (с возрастом только лучше). Тем более если у вас ответ имеет отличия от ответов других, то вас можно было бы натолкнуть друг на друга. Для чего спросите вы? А я скажу - в споре рождается истина.

Comment: Да здесь спорить не о чем. Нужно вникать в природу асинхронного программирования, а не теорию пережевывать, а перебороть все страхи и начать писать код. Постепенно все нюансы прояснятся. Для начала хватит этого: 1) `async` без `await` не использовать 2) таски обязательно ожидать и именно с помощью `await` 3) аккуратно ловить все исключения. Вот вам еще пучок матчасти [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1385259/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смешались в кучу люди, кони.

1. Ключевое слово `async` указывает только на то, что метод может иметь внутри себя вызовы с ключевым словом `await`. Всё, больше ни на что оно не указывает. Будут там эти вызовы или нет - уж как напишете. Если вызовов `await` там нет, то метод явно не асинхронный.

```
async void SimpleAsync() {} // пустой метод - обычный синхронный пустой метод
```

2. Ключевое слово `await` говорит о попытке выполнить Task асинхронно. Какой то таск можно выполнить асинхронно, а какой то не получится. А всё потому, что Task - это по сути абстракция какой то работы, а раз это абстракция, то и у разных тасков будет разное поведение. Например, если таск уже завершен, то уже позно пытаться выполнить его асинхронно.

```
async void SimpleAsync2() {await Task.FromResult(0);}
```

В примере выше мы патаемся выполнить таск асинхронно, но там нечего выполнять, так как таск был создан уже выполненным. Потому код выше опять, просто синхронный код.

3. Ну а теперь давайте попробуем понять, что такое "асинхронный вызов". По идее, если ты вызываешь какой то код, но не блокируешь там самым свой поток, то вызов будет асинхронным.

```
async void SimpleAsync3() {await Task.Run(()=>Thread.Sleep(1000));}
```

Асинхронный ли это вызов? Ну, по идее да, с точки зрения языка программирования. Но, является ли это асинхронным выполнением? Давайте глянем на [определение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416086/179763)

> Асинхронное исполнение

> Асинхронность (asynchrony) подразумевает, что операция может быть выполнена кем-то на стороне: удаленным веб-узлом, сервером или другим устройством за пределами текущего вычислительного устройства.

> Основное свойство таких операций в том, что начало такой операции требует значительно меньшего времени, чем основная работа. Что позволяет выполнять множество асинхронных операций одновременно даже на устройстве с небольшим числом вычислительных устройств.

В коде выше, будет ли операция выполнена на стороне? Нет, ведь в коде выше просто один поток будет асинхронно ожидать, пока другой поток будет заблокирован. То есть пример выше просто какой то многопоточный код с асинхронным ожиданием, то есть код вроде как использует асинзхронные механизмы, но не является "асинхронным выполнением".

4. Ну тогда давайте поглядим на код, который не только выглядит как асинхронный, но и работает как асинхронный.

```
async void SimpleAsync4() {await File.ReadAllTextAsync("..."); }
```

Ну вот выше код читает текст из файла. То есть это I/O операция. Такую операцию должен выполнять жесткий диск, а не процессор. То есть, во время считывания данных, процессор не делает ничего, никакие потоки не блокированы, просто жесткий диск работает, а проц занимается своими делами, пока жесткий диск все не считает. То есть операция считывания выполняется на устройстве жесткого диска и CPU не блокирован. Вот это называется асинхронное выполнение.

Можно [еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/781007/179763). Вот, рассмотрим класс

```
public class Wnd : Window
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> s;

    public Wnd()
    {
        s = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();     
        this.Closed+= (sender, args) => s.SetResult(this);
    }

    public Task ShowAsync()
    {
        this.Show();
        return s.Task;
    }
}
```

Это обычное окно и возможность асинхронного ожидания момента, когда юзер это окно закроет. Пример вызова

```
async Task AsyncBased()
{
    var i = DoSmthg();
    var wnd = new Wnd();
    await wnd.ShowAsync();
    DoSmthgElse(i);
}
```

Что тут происходит? Мы в коде асинхронно ждем юзера. То есть вычислительной задачи вообще нет. Операция на стороне юзера - он когда закончит работать с окном, его закроет - только тогда вызов `await wnd.ShowAsync();` завершится. При этом никакой поток не заблокирован, ничего не вычисляется. Асинхронное выполнение? Вполне, ведь операция выполняется юзером, а не устройством.

5. Ну а теперь вопрос. Ок, мы поняли, что есть "асинхронный вызов", но он не означает "асинронное выполнение". То есть вы можете что то вызвать асинхронно, но выполнение будет синхронным. Или асинхронным. Уж как напишете.
   А может ли быть асинхронное выполнение без асинхронного вызова? (читай без async/await)? Вообще то да. Ничего вам не мешает запустить операцию на другом устройстве и когда она закончится, что то сделать. Ну как пример

```
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) => {Console.WriteLine("Completed");}
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("...."));
```

Что вы видите выше, мы делаем запрос по сети и отреагируем на него тогда, когда он будет закончен. То есть такая логика строится на событиях и тоже ничего не блокирует. Это называется `Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)` и считается устаревшим подходом, просто потому, что с ним ваш код выглядит как лапша событий. Асинхронное ли это выполнение в примере? Да. Асинхронный ли метод, что это вызвает? Нет, обычный метод, никаких async/await.

На самом деле [EAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap) - это не удобно, потому ему на замену пришло [TAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) (`Task-based asynchronous pattern` ). TAP - это как раз про async/await, но по сути это примерно то же самое, что EAP, но только более юзер-френдли для программиста. Чтобы это понять, можно почитать всякие статьи, как конвертировать [EAP в TAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-wrap-eap-patterns-in-a-task) ну или вот вам [живой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828845/179763). Гарантирует ли наличие событий какое то асинхронное выполнение? Конечно нет. Можно ли использовать EAP для асинхронных вызовов - если вы себя не любите и хотите страдать, то можете.

Можно ли использовать EAP/TAP для асинхронного вызова? Можно. Гарантирует ли это асинхронное выполнение? Конечно нет.

Comment: Полезное сравнение асинхронного исполнения и асинхронного вызова.  Хотя термин асинхронное исполнение с понятием асинхронного метода не связали. Исходя из прочитанного такой связи нет. Понятие асинхронного метода упоминали 2 раза:  тут "Асинхронный ли метод, что это вызвает? Нет, обычный метод, никаких async/await." и тут "Если вызовов await там нет, то метод явно не асинхронный.".  То есть оба раза как пример чем асинхронный метод не есть. Из чего можно сделать догадку что вы завязываете понятие асинхронного метода на ключевое слово await (По внутреннему устройству о котором писал aepot).

Comment: а его и не надо связывать - в этом же и сесть идея. У вас может быть метод асинзронным (с точки зрения спецификации языка), но при этом в нем не будет вызова асинхронной операции, и также у вас метод может быть синхзронным, но при этом может вызвать асинхронную операцию. Если вас интересует именно понятие асинхронного метода с точки зрения языка, а не с точки зрения того, что метод делает, то вот [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/13.3.php) можно почитать.

Comment: Metanit не первоисточник. Ну если его посмотреть то это определение только в рамках языка C# определенной версии, которое к тому же не соответствует документации майкрософта приведенной мной выше. В дополнение это определение более узкое чем то что писал aepot. По его определению можно написать свой язык myC# и свои ключевые слова (с люмыми названиями myAsyc/myAwait), свою машину состояний и там могут быть асинхронные методы, а вот по определению  Metanit - не совсем (хоть можно сделать и полностью аналогично).

Comment: А так как metanit не первоисточник и создает не с чем не совпадающее определение, то его не особо хотелось бы рассматривать.

Comment: Мне интересно что вообще представлтять когда тебе говорят словосочетание асинхронный метод. Четкие определения и то что могут подразумевать.

Comment: вы определитесь до конца, что именно вы спрашиваете. Я вам уже показал, что метод может быть асинзронным с точки зрения языка, может быть методом, который действительно выполняет асинзронную операцию и что нет однозначной связи между первым и вторым. Вы мне какие то аргументы приводите, но я не пойму к чему они. Может быть метод асинзронным с точки зрения языка? Да, может. Может метод запустить асинхронную операцию? да, может. Если ли однозначная связь между первым и вторым? Не особо. О чем тут еще спорить - я не знаю.

Comment: Если у вас вопросы, почему в МСДН так или сяк что то написали - мне неведомо что, как и зачем они пишут. Если вас интересует именно точность определения для C# - ну читайте спецификацию языка, там определение может быть, а может и не быть - я не буду в ней ковыряться, я на C# не прогаммирую.

Comment: Вот допустим нет языка C# и .NET. В таком случае как бы вы понимали фразу 'асинхронный метод' если вам ее скажут другие люди, которые не важно на чем программируют? Какая будет ваша реакция - "что? никогда не слышал о таком? поясните за слова" или "тут может быть много значений! поясните за слова!" или  может подумаете "это же метод, который использует распространненный в разных языках синтаксический сахар async/await, сахар который создает машину состояний и позволяет задавать продолжения - да может не кто не вводил такого понятия, но в обиходе его так все и используют".

Comment: `асинхронный метод` - это понятие, привязанное к языку. Без языка нет такого понятия. `async/await` это просто ключевые слова конкретного языка. В одном языке оно может означать одни вещи, в другом - другие. Машина состояний - это конкретная реализация конкретного языка. Вон, в java нет никакого async/await - значит ли это, что в java нет асинхронных вызовов? Конечно не значит.

Comment: когда мне скажут, что где то есть асинхронный метод, я ни о чем не подумаю. Когда мне скажут, что в конкретной программе какая то работа выполняется асинхронно, я подумаю о той асинхронности, которую привел в своем ответе.

Comment: Теперь ваша позиция понятна.

Answer (score 1):

В первоначальной версии вашего сообщения до редактирования был такие вопросы:

> Значит вроде как есть такое понятие не завязанное на ключевое слово?

Да, есть. [Asynchronous programming patterns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/). До появления TAP с ключевыми словами `async` и `await`, были модели асинхронного программирования EAP и APM, где таких слов нет.

> Какой первоисточник этого понятия? Какое значение оно имеет сейчас? Или это как и многие другие термины в которые на слуху но четкого определения не имеют - кто как хочет так и понимает?

Информационные технологии появились относительно недавно и стремительно развиваются. И если в других областях человеческой деятельности термины и понятия выпестовывались на протяжении веков, то в IT пришлось придумывать их на ходу и зачастую заимствовать из других наук, профессий. Например, многое было заимствовано из сферы строительства: термины "архитектура", "build" (сбилдить, построить) и пр.

Понятие асинхронности существует и в других областях.
Например, асинхронные шарниры неравных угловых скоростей в механике. Благодаря им валы могут вращаться с разными скоростями.
Асинхронные электродвигатели в электрике. У которых частота вращения ротора не равна частоте вращения магнитного поля.

> существуют ли такие методы, которые могут быть вызваны не блокирующе, но сами не содержат AMI?

[File IO improvements in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/file-io-improvements-in-dotnet-6/) - я читал и за голову хватался... Сколько же багов в реализации асинхронности. Снаружи API вроде как асинхронный, а внутри то лишние потоки создаются, то блокировки используются...
Что-то уже исправлено, а что-то ещё предстоит исправлять. А некоторые проблемы вообще неизвестно как решать, потому что кросс-платформенность (чёрт бы её побрал)! В Винде, Линухе и Макоси по-разному реализованы системные API, в итоге сложно привести их к общему интерфейсу.

Опять же, мне встречались сведения, что провайдеры многих баз данных до сих пор являются синхронными, хотя их .NET-реализации предоставляют асинхронные методы в соответствии с рекомендациями Microsoft. Причём это не проблема серверов СУБД, это проблема клиентов, которые будут к ним обращаться.

---

Среди всего многообразия методов `DelayAsync`, которые вы привели, нет ещё одного:

```
Task DelayAsync() { return Task.Delay(1); }
```

Здесь не эвейтится внутренний метод, а сразу возвращается. Это возможно потому, что `Task` является awaitable объектом.
Соответственно, не нужен модификатор `async`.