# Как обработать событие в другом потоке?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть объект у закрытой библиотеке, на событие которого я подписываюсь, но оно возникает в основном потоке. И поэтому я не могу использовать `AutoResetEvent`, потому что в одном и том же потоке всё работает. А как можно реализовать так, чтобы событие возникало в новом потоке?

```
listenerPrice.Handler += new Listener.MessageHandler(MessageHandlerClientPrice);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обработчик будет вызван в том потоке, где его вызывает отправитель события — в вашем случае, в главном потоке. Это обойти невозможно.

Вы можете, однако, получив событие, перебросить обработку в другой поток. Например, через `Task.Run`.

---

Для вашего случая:

```
// начало
// инициировать действие
// дождаться event'а
// конец
```

нужно переписать код в таком виде:

```
Listener.MessageHandler h = null;
h = (args) =>
{
    listenerPrice.Handler -= h;
    // конец
};
// начало
listenerPrice.Handler += h;
// инициировать действие
```

Ещё более хороший вариант — перейти на async/await. При этом ваш код будет таким:

```
// начало
// инициировать действие
await CallbackReceived();
// конец
```

Метод `CallbackReceived` можно имплементировать, например, как описано здесь: [В чем смысл TaskCompletionSource<T> и когда его лучше использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/780270/10105)

Comment: Хм... а разве события обрабатываются не в отдельном потоке по очереди?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Нет. События обрабатываются синхронно в вызывающем потоке.

Comment: @VladD Вот я тоже думал, что во внешнем потоке. Попробую сейчас Ваш вариант, отпишусь после

Comment: @VladD так, я прочитал, в самом колбэке вы хотите, чтобы реализация через другой поток была. Но мне нужно, чтобы при использовании `AutoResetEvent` основной поток остановился и ждал, а параллельно второй поток отследил событие и после его обработки основной поток продолжил. Поэтому даже вызов должен быть во внешнем потоке.
А что тогда, если создать поток параллельно и в нем подписаться на ВСЕ мои события, а их штук 8. И он будет висеть до окончания программы. Тем самым параллельно вызываться. Это нормальное решение?

Comment: @Fresto: «мне нужно, чтобы при использовании `AutoResetEvent` основной поток остановился и ждал» — а вот этого не понял. Откуда вдруг взялся `AutoResetEvent`? Что именно с чем вы хотите синхронизировать?

Comment: @VladD Хм... точно помню, что где-то читал про отдельный поток. Или я с чем-то другим путаю... Ну точно что-то в контексте событий и делегатов.

Comment: @VladD У меня есть 1 метод, в нем 2 действия. После первого действия я получаю колбэк, И чтобы я выполнил второе действие, я должен получить некую информацию из этого колбэка. Поэтому поток должен ожидать, пока сработает колбэк, для этого я сделал `AutoResetEvent`. Но тут оказывается, что колбэк в моем же поток вызывается и поток просто остановился и всё, поэтому я спрашивал, как колбэк в паралелльный поток засунуть)

Comment: @Fresto: Эээ... Стойте. Какая-то фигня выходит. Есть два варианта: (1) Либо `callback` вызывается сразу же. Тогда вам не нужно ждать, у вас тут же есть результат. (2) Либо `callback` вызывается потом. Тогда есл вы заблокируете главный поток в ожидании, то событие никак не сможет прийти, ведь оно должно отправится в главном потоке, а он как раз и заблокирован. Это очевидный deadlock.

Comment: @Fresto: Думаю, вы должны отказаться от идеи выполнить второе действие в той же функции, а выполнить его в callback'е. Или перейти на async/await.

Comment: @VladD Так, стоп, поэтому же и нужна штука как `AutoResetEvent` тип она ожидает того, что в каком-то другом потоке выполнится метод `Set()`. Колбэк вызывается сразу, но не так быстро, как основной поток перейдет ко второму действию. В первом действии там на сервер пока отправится, пока там обработается, это конечно секунды, но не настолько быстро, чтобы просто перейти к след строчке кода ( ко 2 действию )

Comment: @Fresto: Нет. `AutoResetEvent` нужен, чтобы дождаться наступления того или иного условия в **другом** потоке. Это ж средство синхронизации потоков. В вашем случае он непригоден.

Comment: @VladD Так я и спрашиваю, а если создать второй поток и в нем подписаться на события и сделать так, чтобы все события в нем вызывали, так можно ведь?

Comment: @Fresto: (1) Нет, так нельзя. Если событие доставляется в главном потоке, оно таки будет доставляться в главном потоке. (2) Даже если и можно было бы, это очень кружной путь. Всё равно что для сложения чисел перевести их в строки, и складывать в столбик в цикле по разрядам, вместо оператора +. Зачем создавать себе лишнюю работу?

Comment: @VladD я вас понял, тогда да. Просто тогда я буду делать велосипед. Тип у меня метод - действи с числами. Колбэк вызывается при любом действии. И я должен сделать глобальную переменную типа действия, указывать её, когда хочу что-то сделать и в колбэке выполнять свою работу, когда именно я складываю, например. Тем самым я перенесу своё второе действие в колбэк. Но мне казалось всегда, что это велосипед.

Comment: @Fresto: Не, велосипед не нужен. У вас что, одна подписка на все случаи жизни? Подпишите нужый код.

Comment: @VladD фишка в том, что я подписываюсь на готовое событие в закрытой библиотеке и нужные данные я могу получить именно там. А это событие как раз такие универсальное для всех видов действий.

Comment: @Fresto: Это неправильно, одна и та же подписка — плохо. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @VladD я вас понял, попробую сделать тогда так, спасибо за пояснения!