# Как организовать синхронизацию потоков?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Есть поток, который в цикле ожидает данные от ком-порта (или любого другого интерфейса) и при их поступлении вызывает событие `OnFrameReceived(...)`. Мне нужно написать блокирующий метод `SendAndWaitReply(...)`, который отправит данные по ком-порту и будет ждать ответа (события `OnFrameReceived`) или таймаута операции (если ответ не придет).

Подскажите, как организовать синхронизацию потока чтения и потока, отправляющего команду?

```
public class Device
{
    Connection connection = new Connection(...);

    public Device()
    {
        connection.FrameReceived += Connection_FrameReceived;
    }

    // Отправить пакет и дождаться ответа/таймаута
    public void SendAndWaitReply(ITxFrame frame)
    {
        bool timeout = false;

        // Отправить пакет и заблокировать поток до наступления таймаута или приема ответа

        if(timeout)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();    
        }
    }

    // Событие приема пакета
    private void Connection_FrameReceived(object sender, RxFrame frame)
    {
        // Разблокировать поток, ожидающий приема пакета

        // Обработка принятого пакета
    }
}
```

Comment: такое ведь лучше делать асинхронно с колбэк методами

Comment: @swd На сколько понял, вам нужна взаимоисключающая блокировка, чтобы не вызывать передачу в случае если идет прием пакетов? [Оператор lock](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

Comment: @ГеннадийП Нет, взаимодействие типа запрос-ответ. Мне нужно после отправки сообщения заблокировать поток и дождаться пока придет ответ или, если ответ не придет, разбудить поток через, например, 3 секунды.

Comment: @Санаев насколько я знаю организовать таймаут асинхронной операции ввода-вывода невозможно без закрытия внутреннего Stream (например NetworkStream или serialPort.BaseStream).

Comment: Можно вот через эту штуку попробовать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780270/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-taskcompletionsourcet-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C . Обернуть событие в Task и асинхронно дождаться.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, можно ли проще:

```
public class Device
{
    private object _sendAndWaitReplySyncObject = new object();
    private AutoResetEvent _frameReceivedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private AutoResetEvent _frameAcceptedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private AutoResetEvent _timeoutEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private ManualResetEvent _outsideSendAndWaitReplyEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    // Отправить пакет и дождаться ответа/таймаута
    public void SendAndWaitReply(object frame)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (_sendAndWaitReplySyncObject)
            {
                // переводим все эвенты в not signaled состояние
                _outsideSendAndWaitReplyEvent.Reset();
                _frameReceivedEvent.Reset();
                _frameAcceptedEvent.Reset();
                _timeoutEvent.Reset();

                // Отправить пакет
                bool timeout = !_frameReceivedEvent.WaitOne(3000);
                if (timeout)
                {
                    _timeoutEvent.Set();
                    // для того, что бы блок finally не сработал раньше времени
                    _frameReceivedEvent.WaitOne();
                    throw new TimeoutException();
                }
                else
                {
                    _frameAcceptedEvent.Set();
                    // для того, что бы блок finally не сработал раньше времени
                    _frameReceivedEvent.WaitOne();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // что бы Connection_FrameReceived не ждал вечно на вызове WaitAll
            _outsideSendAndWaitReplyEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    // Событие приема пакета
    private void Connection_FrameReceived(object sender, object frame)
    {
        _frameReceivedEvent.Set(); // Разблокировать поток, ожидающий приема пакета
        int index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[]
        {
            _outsideSendAndWaitReplyEvent,
            _frameAcceptedEvent,
            _timeoutEvent
        });
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                // событие сработало вне метода SendAndWaitReply
                break;

            case 1:
                _frameReceivedEvent.Set();
                // Обработка принятого пакета
                break;

            case 2:
                _frameReceivedEvent.Set();
                // сработал _timeoutEvent
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В первом случае нет реализации таймаута - если не придет ответ, поток не разблокируется. Во втором случае возможна гонка. Нужно как-то синхронизировать обработку таймаута и прием ответа, иначе, если if (evt.WaitOne(5000)) вернет false, и в этот момент произойдет событие OnFrameReceived, то будет и детектирован таймаут и обработано принятое сообщение.

Comment: @swd что значит "и в этот момент произойдет событие OnFrameReceived"? События должны срабатывать в независимости от того, подписан кто-то на них или нет.

Comment: @swd Я изменил слегка код, и добавил `lock`, теперь не должно быть гонки. Только вот непонятно, что должно происходить, если 10 потоков одновременно захотят вызвать `SendAndWaitReply`. В моем случае возможны очень долгие ожидания

Comment: подкорректировал вопрос, добавил код, что бы было понятнее, что я имею ввиду. Если SendAndWaitReply генерирует TimeoutException, то обработки ответа происходить не должно

Comment: @swd обновил ответ