# Насколько правильно или не правильно делать ожидание Func<String,String,Task>func при вызове await func.Invoke(string,string); в C# и почему?

Tags: c#, async-await

Насколько правильно или не правильно делать ожидание Func<String,String,Task>func при вызове await func.Invoke(string,string); в C# и почему? А так же как вызовется этот метод в итоге? Синхронно или асинхронно?

```
public class A
{
    public Func<string, string, Task> ResiveMassage;
    public void Start()
    {
        B b = new B(ResiveMassage);
        while (true)
        {
           
            _ = Task.Run(async () => await b.Resive()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
public class B
{
    string h = "Hello";
    string w = "World";
    Func<String, String, Task> ResiveMassage;
    public B(Func<String, String, Task> resiveMassage)
    {
        ResiveMassage = resiveMassage;
    }
    public async Task Resive()
    {
        await ResiveMassage?.Invoke(h,w);
       // await Task.Delay(5000);
    } 
}
public class C
{
    public void Strat()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.ResiveMassage += ResiveMessageAsync;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>a.Start()));
        thread.Start();

    }
    async Task ResiveMessageAsync(string h, string w)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine($"{h} {w}"));
       // await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.Strat();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Не делать ожидание совсем - практически всегда неправильно. Вы можете делать ожидание сразу, можете делать его позже, но делать надо. Почитайте про проблемы `async void`, так вот вызов любого метода без ожидания рождает [те же проблемы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming), что и `async void`. Тема в сети разжевана очень хорошо.

Comment: Второй вопрос - любой асинхронный метод выполняется синхронно до тех пор, пока первый встретившийся в нем `await` не вернет ему `Task`, чтобы пробросить его дальше по стеку вызовов. И вот как только это произошло - метод начинает выполняться асинхронно. Почитайте про Машину состояний `async/await`.

Comment: @aepot, даже не просто `Task`, а именно еще не завершенный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совершенно неважно, вызываете ли вы делегат или просто метод. И то и другое может завершиться синхронно, например.

Здесь даже мудрить с классами не надо, чтобы понять.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await DoA();
    await DoB();
    await DoC();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static async Task DoA()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}


private static async Task DoB()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

private static Task DoC()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    return Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Здесь метод `DoA()` выполнится синхронно, остальные асинхронно. Но `Console.WriteLine()` везде выполнятся синхронно. Подробнее как это работает можно узнать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth).

Так же популярная ошибка начинающих разработчиков - путать асинхронность и многопоточность. Это вообще не похожие друг на друга вещи. Первое - это организация кода так, чтобы он продолжал выполняться по завершению какой-то операции. Второе - много потоков. В асинхронной операции может вообще [не использоваться дополнительных потоков](https://habr.com/ru/post/216659/).

Что делает `await Task.Run`:

- Спавнит новый поток или берет из пула потоков существующий, если уже есть такой
- Запускает в этом потоке код
- Возвращает `Task`, дающий возможность асинхронно дождаться конца выполнения кода в другом потоке

То есть здесь присутствует и асинхронность и многопоточность, и выполняют они совершенно разные задачи. Многопоточность вам позволяет запустить CPU-зависимый код не занимая текущий поток, а асинхронность дождаться конца его выполнения. Если бы асинхронность не использовалась, как таковая, использовался бы либо колбэк, что и есть сама суть асинхронности на низком уровне, либо просто `Sleep`, что вообще костыль и бессмысленно.

Нет смысла выполнять код в другом потоке, когда текущий блокируется на время выполнения. Ну потому что для выполнения куска синхронного кода достаточно одного потока, все что больше - излишество. За исключением конечно же ситуаций, когда вам реально нужны распеделенные вычисления. Тогда многопоточность к вашим услугам.

Далее, нужно понять, почему `await` без `async` нельзя, а наоборот - можно. Потому что первый генерирует [машину состояний](https://habr.com/ru/post/260217/), а второй ее использует. Сгенерить машину состояний и не использовать ее конечно можно (метод `DoA`), но какой в этом смысл? Смысл в машине состояний появляется тогда, когда у нее существует более двух состояний. В противном случае достаточно либо обычного ветвления `if-else`, либо вообще код будет линейный.

> Насколько правильно или не правильно делать ожидание `Func<String,String,Task>func` при вызове `await func.Invoke(string,string)` в C# и почему?

Этот вопрос по своей сути поставлен неправильно. Все зависит от реализации самого метода. Если метод совсем не ожидать, то зачем в принципе асинхронность нужна? Как я чуть выше писал, вся суть в асинхронности в ожидании `await`. Нет `await` - нет асинхронности, ну только если вы не обвешаетесь колбэками или континуациями `.ContinueWith()`. Ведь поведение `await` можно эмулировать с помощью написания самого обычного кода. `async/await` по своей сути - синтаксический "сахар", позволяющий писать с виду линейный код, когда внутри по своей сути он таковым не является. Для новичка выглядит как магия, но это до тех пор, пока он не закончит путать асинхронность с многопоточностью.

> А так же как вызовется этот метод в итоге? Синхронно или асинхронно?

Вызовется или выполнится (завершится)?

- Если "вызовется", то **все методы вызываются синхронно**, и вызвать метод асинхронно технически невозможно.
- Если речь про "завершится", то совершенно неважно, что там этот метод возвращает, главное чтобы возвращал `Task` - первое условие асинхронности. У вас `Task` возвращается, это говорит о том, что метод **может** завершиться асинхронно, а может и синхронно. Надо смотреть, что там внутри, смотрим: `await Task.Run(() => ...` и больше ничего, но `await` есть, он возвращает тот самый заветный `Task`. Логичный вопрос: а метод `Task.Run()` может завершиться асинхронно, там есть `await` внутри? Грубо говоря "есть", но "нет", там есть специальный "ожидатель", код, который исходя из того, что там с запущенным потоком происходит, меняет внутреннее состояние того самого `Task`, который он вам вернул. Класс, управляющий состоянием `Task`, называется `TaskCompletionSource`. Вот [весьма хорошее объяснение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/780292/373567), как это работает.

Так как все-таки, **синхронно или асинхронно**?

**Асинхронно, но это не точно.** Потому что есть `Task` и есть `await`. А почему не точно? А потому что за запуск тасок отвечает `TaskScheduler` ([ссылка .NET Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)), а он [может вообще быть синхронным](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously?view=netframework-4.8), это уж как вы пожелаете.

[Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async) - это просто. :)

Comment: Огромное Спасибо! Просто от души понял всё что упустил! Да вопрос был задан не корректно, но ответ 100%