# Использование ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Смотрю пример кода. Удивило, что сначала `ConfigureAwait(false)` вызывается на `httpClient.GetStringAsync`, а затем на `sourceStream.WriteAsync`. Насколько я знаю `ConfigureAwait(false)` указывает, что код должен продолжать выполняться не в контексте `UI`, а в контексте таска. Зачем тогда 2 раза его вызывать?

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    //до этого момента всё выполняется в UI контексте?
    string content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com").
        ConfigureAwait(false); 
    //после выполнения верхней строчки остальной код который внизу будет выполняться в контексте веррхнего таска?
    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream("temp.html", FileMode.Create, 
        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length).
            ConfigureAwait(false);
       //будь дальше какой-то код, в контексте какого потока он выполнялся б?
    };
}
```

Comment: потому что они применяются **к разным** таскам?

Comment: @Grundy, Не совсем понял. Вы хотите сказать, что если не указывать `ConfigureAwait(false)`, то таск работает в новом потоке, но использует контекст `UI` потока?

Comment: не, я вроде совсем не это сказал :)

Comment: @Grundy, Я уже себе чуть накрутил) Сейчас дополню вопрос.

Comment: @Lightness Мой ответ кажется недостаточно полным?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Смотрите.

`ConfigureAwait(false)` означает, и правда, «мне всё равно, в каком <del>потоке</del> `SynchronizationContext`'е будет выполняться хвост метода».

То есть первый `ConfigureAwait(false)` может отправить «хвост» метода в фоновый поток. Но именно что *может*, а не *должен*! Если по какой-то причине первый таск выполнится синхронно (например, строка есть уже в кэше), то перевод в другой `SynchronizationContext` осуществлён **не будет**, и выполнение будет продолжаться в исходном контексте.

Если при этом второй `await` не снабжён конструкцией `ConfigureAwait(false)`, то хвост метода будет выполняться снова-таки в исходном контексте — то есть, в вашем случае в контексте UI.

Таким образом, для библиотечных методов, которые не общаются с UI, практически необходимо к *каждому* внутреннему `await`'у добавлять `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

---

Понятно, что дописывать к каждому из `await`'ов `ConfigureAwait(false)` немного лень. Можно вместо этого использовать такой трюк: «сбежать» на пул потоков в самом начале, и не беспокоиться об этом больше. Это можно сделать при помощи такой конструкции:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await AsyncHelper.RedirectToThreadPool();
    // всё, мы больше не в UI-контексте, гарантировано

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com"); 
    // ...
}
```

Вспомогательные классы (взяты [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458425/10105)):

```
static class AsyncHelper
{
    public static ThreadPoolRedirector RedirectToThreadPool() =>
        new ThreadPoolRedirector();
}

public struct ThreadPoolRedirector : INotifyCompletion
{
    // awaiter и awaitable в одном флаконе
    public ThreadPoolRedirector GetAwaiter() => this;

    // true означает выполнять продолжение немедленно 
    public bool IsCompleted => Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread;

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) =>
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => continuation());

    public void GetResult() { }
}
```

(идея взята из [*Stephen Toub* `await anything;`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/))

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме от того же Stephen Toub: [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) (и [русский перевод](https://habr.com/ru/post/482354/)) — спасибо [@aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot) за наводку.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61522/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd--configureawaitfalse).

Comment: Что такое хвост метода?

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov: Хороший вопрос ;-) В примере ТС код линеен, так что «хвост» — это код метода после данного `await` (включая использование результата, если тип `await`-выражения не `void`, например, присвоение результата переменной `content` в примере ТС). В более сложных случаях (например, а присутствии циклов) это так называемый continuation: часть исполнения функции от момента завершения `await`.

Comment: [Чтиво](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/), [перевод на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/482354/).

Comment: @aepot: `await Task.Yield().ConfigureAwait(false)` — думаете, гарантирует уход на пул? Статью читал, Stephen Toub — наше всё. Ссылка хорошая, да.

Comment: @VladD все гарантии выходят из того, может ли `Task.Yield` завершитсься синхронно. Если нет, значит уход в пул гарантирован. Логично же? Насколько мне известно, `Yield()` не может завершиться синхронно: [1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L2578), [2](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/YieldAwaitable.cs#L50).

Comment: @VladD ахаха, стоп, `Yield()` не позволяет `ConfigureAwait()` как и континуаций. :) Что-то меня заклинило. Простите.

Comment: @aepot: Точно, и я протупил, `Task.Yield()` вообще не возвращает `Task`.

Answer (score 17):

Немного теории:

При использовании ключевого слова `await` компилятор делает много чего интересного, но в данном случае нас интересует, то что происходит запоминание (*на самом деле запоминается и другие контексты*) контекста синхронизации `SynchronizationContext`, который предназначен для исполнения кода в потоке конкретного вида. В классе `SynchronizationContext` есть важный метод `Post`, который гарантирует, что переданный делегат будет исполняться в правильном контексте.

Так вот, мы помним, что код, предшествующий первому `await`, *исполняется в вызывающем потоке*, но что происходит, когда исполнение вашего метода возобновляется после `await`? На самом деле, *в большинстве случаев* он также *исполняется в вызывающем потоке*, несмотря на то, что в промежутке вызывающий поток мог делать что-то еще. Для достижения такого эффекта текущий контекст `SynchronizationContext` **сохраняется** (это происходит при встрече оператора `await`). Далее, когда метод возобновляется, компилятор вставляет вызов `Post`, чтобы исполнение возобновилось в запомненном контексте. Как правило, вызов этого метода обходится сравнительно дорого. Поэтому, чтобы избежать накладных расходов, **.NET** не вызывает `Post`, если запомненный контекст синхронизации совпадает с текущим на момент завершения задачи. Однако если контексты синхронизации различаются, то необходим дорогостоящий вызов `Post`. Если производительность стоит на первом месте или речь идет о библиотечном коде, которому безразлично, в каком потоке выполняться, то, возможно, не имеет смысла нести такие расходы. Поэтому, в таком случае следует вызвать метод `ConigureAwait(false)` перед тем как ждать его. Важно понимать, что данный метод задуман как способ информирования **.NET** о том, что **вам безразлично, в каком потоке будет возобновлено выполнение**. Если этот поток не очень важен, например взят из пула, то исполнение кода в нем и продолжится. Но если поток по какой-то причине важен, то **.NET** предпочтет освободить его для других дел, а исполнение вашего метода продолжить в потоке, взятом из пула. Решение о том, важен поток или нет, принимается на основе анализа текущего контекста синхронизации.

---

Это была вводная, а теперь слегка модернизируем ваш пример. Функционал, отвечающий за получение контента с сайта `www.microsoft.com` вынесем в отдельный метод. Обратите внимание, что `ConigureAwait(false)` здесь уже не используется.

```
 public async Task<string> GetContentAsync()
 {
     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     string content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");
     return content;
 }
```

Далее слегка изменим обработчик события клик:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Обратите внимание, что здесь мы не используем оператор `await`
    // Кроме того, все что идет ниже, нам уже не интересно, так как мы попали в deadlock
    var content = GetContentAsync().Result;

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream("temp.html", FileMode.Create, 
    FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length).
        ConfigureAwait(false);
    };
}
```

Что же тут происходит и почему возникает deadlock.

1. Вызов свойства `Result` блокирует вызывающий поток, пока асинхронная операция `GetContentAsync` не будет завершена.
2. Так в методе `GetContentAsync` используется ключевое слово `await` произойдет сохранение текущего `SynchronizationContext` в данном случае контекста `UI`.
3. После того, как метод `GetContentAsync` выполнится, необходимо будет возобновить работу метода `Button_Click` в сохраненном контексте `SynchronizationContext`, но сделать этого не получится т.к. основной поток в режиме ожидания из-за вызова `Result`.

Собственно резюме:

Если производительность стоит на первом месте или речь идет о **библиотечном коде**, которому безразлично, в каком потоке выполняться, следует использовать `ConigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Я бы не советовал использовать `ConigureAwait(false)` как инструмент избегания взаимоблокировок. Он слишком многословен для этой цели.

Comment: @PavelMayorov насколько я знаю общими рекомендациями при работе с `async/await` является использование `ConfigureAwait(false)` везде где это возможно, плюс не использовать блокировки в коде, и стараться применять асинхронный подход везде. Что касается блокировок, какие рекомендации будут у вас?

Comment: Явно перейти в контекст по умолчанию, после чего забыть про `ConigureAwait(false)`

Comment: Всё же здесь не будет Deadlock, здесь будет обычный переход из асинхронного кода в синхронный с ожиданием результата благодаря Result. Поток Button_Click будет ждать исполнения потока GetContentAsync(). В то время как GetContentAsync никогда не будет ждать исполнения потока Button_Click 
C await невозможен deadlock на пустом месте, как это было со старым подходом с тасками и WaitAll() вместо await WhanAll() (источник - экзамен MS 70-843)

Answer (score 6):

Последующие вызывы `ConfigureAwait(false)` никак не влияют на контекст синхронизации. Метод всё равно выполняется не UI-потоке.

Но я в своём коде тоже так поступаю. Это делается как правило хорошего тона. Чтобы в случае удаления одного из `await`-конструкций метод не сломался.

Comment: А почему он должен сломаться?

Comment: Из-за того, что вообще без `ConfigureAwait(false)`  могут возникать deadlock в вызывающем коде.

Answer (score 3):

Для упрощения работы с ConfigureAwait(false) Можно использовать

[Fody ConfigureAwait](https://github.com/distantcam/ConfigureAwait)

Your code

```
using Fody;

[ConfigureAwait(false)]
public class MyAsyncLibrary
{
    public async Task MyMethodAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        await Task.Delay(20);
    }

    public async Task AnotherMethodAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(30);
    }
}
```

What gets compiled

```
public class MyAsyncLibrary
{
    public async Task MyMethodAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Task.Delay(20).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task AnotherMethodAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(30).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я помню несколько багов, обсуждавшихся здесь, с автоимплементацией INPC у Fody. А уж в такой тонкой материи, как асинхронность, я бы точно не доверял автоматической генерации.

Comment: Ну в итоге то ты сам можешь посмотреть реальный генерируемый код и решить доверять или нет

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере просто программист с опытом работы с тасками применил устаревший поход для await:

```
private Task<string> ReadFileAsync() // no async key word. Need to warry about context and threads and use ConfigureAwait(false)
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
        //some async work
    });
}
//... 
Task<string> result = ReadFileAsync.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Скорее всего именно смесь 2х подходов и ввела в заблуждение. Метод ConfigureAwait в вашем примере просто не нужен, он вообще роли не играет, т.к. уже есть await для которого будет сгенерирована отдельная асинхронная обёртка, метод вернёт Task и только потом дождётся результата.

Всё это будет возвращено в тот поток, который вызвал асинхронную задачу. 
Проблема была бы возможна лишь в том случае, если бы в это время вызывающий поток занимался выполнением какой-то другой долго задачей. Тогда, для экономии времени мы бы использовали ConfigureAwait, что звучало бы как "Уже вернулся? Бери любой свободный поток, забей на контекст и работай дальше" но такое в принципе не возможно в подобном коде. Здесь фактически 1 задача и мы дожидаемся её завершения.

и ваш код должен был бы выглядеть правильно вот так:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream("temp.html", FileMode.Create, 
        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
        // весь код после WriteAsync выполняется в контексте UI, но на время, пока будет выполняться асинхронный код WriteAsync, поток UI благодаря await не будет ждать ответа (не будет зависания) и вернётся только после завершения асинхронной задачи (await). Внутри компилятором будет сгенерирован код, который это и сделает.
    };
}
```

Вот аналогичная ситуация описана в книге для экзамена майкрософт 70-843 на стр. 26. Уж куда более достоверный источник, чем статьи в интернете, где всё в кучу собрано и async\await и СonfigureAwait():

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  long noOfValues = long.Parse(NumberOfValuesTextBox.Text);
  ResultTextBlock.Text = "Calculating";
  double result = await (asyncComputeAverages(noOfValues));
  ResultTextBlock.Text = "Result: " + result.ToString();
}
```

> The keyword precedes a call of a method that will return the task to
>   be performed. The compiler will generate code that will cause the
>   async method to return to the caller at the point the await is
>   reached. It will then go on to generate code that will perform the
>   awaited action asynchronously and then continue with the body of the
>   async method. In the case of the Button_Click method in Listing 1-32,
>   this means that the result is displayed upon completion of the task
>   returned by asyncComputeAverages. The code does not block the user
>   interface when it runs, the display is updated on the correct thread
>   (the original event handler), and it is very simple to use.

или [на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/257221/)

PS

Попробую объяснить на примере тренера, футболистов и мячей. Где мяч - это поток. 
Тренер разговаривает с футболистом (синхронное выполнение). Тренер может пнуть мячь и сказать беги. Так он может сделать для всех 11 футболистов с 11 мячами-потоками. 
Но в твоём коде он делает следующее:

1. разговаривает
2. пинает мяч.
3. ждёт пока футболист его принесёт, при этом сам занят другими делами, не занимает мяч.
4. дальше разговаривает
5. дальше пинает мяч в др. сторону.

ConfigureAwait(false) нужно было бы для случая:

1. тренер разговаривает с первым футболистом
2. пинает мяч, первый футболист убежал, забрав поток-мяч
3. тренер разговаривает со вторым футболистом
4. в это время первый прибежал, ждёт новый удар. Но тренер все ещё говорит со 2ым футболистом.
5. Так вот в случае с ConfigureAwait(false) футболист берёт любой свободный мяч и, не отвлекая тренера, продолжает тренировку (бьёт мяч и убегает).
   Потому что ему уже не важен контекст (указания тренера) или он всё записал на бумажечку(сохранил контекст)