# Использование async/await для предотвращения блокировки интерфейса

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь добавить в базу 10000 записей используя EF и AddRange(), а также SaveChangesAsync(). Однако все равно при этом зависает интерфейс. Подскажите как это можно исправить?

Код добавления в бд:

```
public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<Bottle> bottles)
{
    using(var context = ContextFactory.CreateContext())
    {
        context.Set<Bottles>().AddRange(bottles);

         await context
            .SaveChangesAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    }

}
```

Метод вызывается так:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bottles = new List<Bottles>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        bottles.Add(new Bottles()
        {
            Name = $"i",
        });
    }

    await AddRangeAsync(bottles);
}
```

БД - Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Какая БД? Покажите код, которым добавляете записи

Comment: Вызоваете как AddRangeAsync?

Comment: @adrug [DbContext.AddRangeAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrangeasync?view=efcore-2.0) `This method is async only to allow special value generators...` скорее всего не поможет

Comment: @adrug Указал в вопросе.

Comment: @HHHack я не уверен, но т.к. никто не ответил.
Попробуйте сделать пул потоков как [сделали  тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681466/4514)

Comment: @adrug Спасибо, это помогло, но если найду еще что то, то отпишусь.

Comment: @HHHack оформи как ответ. Многие ищущие читают только заголовок и первые пару строк.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем помогли пару вариантов:

1) Взят отсюда - [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681382/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-configureawaitfalse/681466#681466)

2) Использовать это :

```
using(var context = ContextFactory.CreateContext())
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        context.Set<Bottles>().AddRange(bottle);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }); 
}
```

3) Создать асинхронный метод создания контекста.

Интерфейс фабрики:

```
public interface IContextFactory
{

    Context CreateContext();

    Task<Context> CreateContextAsync();
}
```

Сама фабрика:

```
public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    public ContextFactory(IConnectionStringProvider connectionStringProvider)
    {
        ConnectionStringProvider = connectionStringProvider;
    }

    private IConnectionStringProvider ConnectionStringProvider { get; }

    public Context CreateContext()
    {
        return new Context(ConnectionStringProvider.ConnectionString);
    }

    public Task<Context> CreateContextAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(new Func<Context>(CreateContext));
    }
}
```

Класс Context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    static Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());
    }

    public Context(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(Bottles.GetConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Добавление в БД:

```
    public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<Bottles> bottles)
    {
        using(var context = await ContextFactory
            .CreateContextAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            context.Set<Bottles>().AddRange(bottles);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

P.S В Entity используется подход Code Base.

Comment: Вы забыли про `await` или `return` перед `SaveChangesAsync`. Кстати, `ConfigureAwait(false)` внутри `Task.Run` можно не делать.