# Когда асинхронная операция выполняется в главном потоке, а когда во вторичном?

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Начал разбираться с асинхронностью и вот не понимаю что происходит при выполнении асинхронных операций.

Есть асинхронный метод:

```
public static async Task DelayOperationAsync()
{
    Operation();
    Task task = Task.Delay(3000);
    Operation();
    await task;   
    Operation();
}
```

Метод Operation :

```
static void Operation()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Operation ThreadID {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Console.WriteLine("Begin");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Finish");
}
```

При `Task.Delay(3000)`, 3 вызов метода Operation происходит во вторичном потоке. А если я меняю задержку например на `Task.Delay(1000)` то все вызовы метода Operation происходят в одном и том же потоке.

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так.

Answer (score 4):

Когда вы пишете `await task;` вы говорите стандартному шедулеру (классу, который решает что в каком потоке выполнить) - `у меня есть таск, после его выполнения мне не важно в каком потоке будет выполнено продолжение`, тогда шедулер смотрит, есть ли у текущего потока контекст синхронизации (он, например, всегда есть у UI потока), если он есть, то продолжение запустится в том же потоке, где таск начался. Если контекста синхронизации нет, то шедулер запускает продолжение таска так, как считает нужным.

Если вы хотите явно выразить ваши предпочтения, то вы можете использовать `ConfigureAwait`, куда вы можете написать ваше предпочтение. Например,

```
await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Явно укажет шедулеру, что вам не важно в каком потоке будет работать продолжение, даже если у текущего потока есть контекст синхронизации. То есть даже если таска началась в потоке с контекстом синхронизации, шедулер не будет это учитывать и запустит продолжение в любом потоке (текущем потоке или потоке из пула потоков).

Подробнее [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/482354/).

Comment: Кстати, рекомендация в статье на хабре о том, будто бы `ConfigureAwait(false)` обязательно уводит выполнение в другой поток, неверна. Один контрпример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681466/10105), ну и continuation может быть при некоторых условиях выполнено сразу ([inline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/when-tpl-task-continuations-are-inlined-and-shouldnt-be/)).

Comment: @VladD уже давненько не пишу на C#, но ты верно говоришь. По большому счету, указывая false мы сообщаем, что нам без разницы, в каком потоке будет продолжение, даже если оно состоится в том же потоке, с которого всё началось. Там много ньюансов на самом деле, переключение на другой поток не происходит сразу. Скорее всего там как со Slim версиями - сначала что то крутится и ждет результата, если его нет за N микросекунд, то досвидания. Если есть - то операция выполнится как синхронная.

Comment: Ого, а на чём, если не на C#?

Comment: @VladD сменил работу и страну. Я теперь вообще редко код пишу, раз в пару месяцев. В основном на java, иногда typescript/javascript. Совсем редко - ruby.