# Как правильно сделать многопоточность?

Tags: c#

У меня есть чекер прокси, я хочу сделать его многопоточным. Как это правильно организовать? У меня была идея засунуть все строки с проксями в список, этот список поделить на равные списки кол-во которых зависит от кол-ва потоков, и в каждый поток загружать свой список. Минус такого велосипеда в том что если один поток закончит работу раньше другого, то он просто завершится а не поможет другому. Вот и думаю, как правильно организовать многопоточность?

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдет [этот способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567), только если вы возмете мою реализацию (не важно, какую именно), и у вас десктопное приложение, не забудьте [покинуть UI контекст синхронизации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681466/373567) перед запуском. А вообще ваша задача - чистой воды шаблон проектирования Producer/Consumer, туда и копать. С асинхронным программированием то знакомы `async/await`?

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что ручное управление потоками нужно в этой задаче.

Кажется, вам нужно опрашивать по кругу заданный список хостов, лимитируя максимальное количество одновременных запросов. Я делал что-то похожее с использованием `System.Timers.Timer`:

```
    const int MAX_PARALLEL_DEGREE = 5;
    const int TRY_EXECUTE_INTERVAL_MS = 100;

    public static void Main() 
    {
        int currParallelDegree = 0;

        var args = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(
            from ch in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" select ch.ToString()
        );

        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TRY_EXECUTE_INTERVAL_MS);

        timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => {
            var p = Interlocked.Increment(ref currParallelDegree);

            if (p <= MAX_PARALLEL_DEGREE) {
                if (args.TryDequeue(out var st)) {
                    try {
                        Console.WriteLine($">>{st} Parallel is {p}");
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine($"<<{st} Parallel is {p}");
                    }
                    finally {
                        args.Enqueue(st);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine($"No available items. Parallel is {p}");
                }     
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine($"Skip due to limiting concurrency. Parallel is {p}");
            }

            Interlocked.Decrement(ref currParallelDegree);
        };

        timer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        timer.Stop();
```

Минусы решения - "прогрев" при начале выполнения (не сразу используется весь допустимый уровень параллелизма) и теоретическая возможность напрасного пропуска тика. Мне обе проблемы были совершенно не критичны.