# Как увеличить память под стек c# visual studio

Tags: c#

Как увеличить память под стек c# visual studio,чтобы избежать stack overflow exception

Comment: Зайти с другой стороны - не писать код, который так сильно углубляется в стек.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458425/10105

Comment: Но вообще-то имеет смысл просто улучшить алгоритм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, речь идет об рекурсивный алгоритмах, так как в любых других ситуациях я не вижу способа словить ошибку переполнения стека.

Так вот, любой рекурсивный алгоритм можно переписать в виде циклов, используя программный стек(`Stack<T>`) и цикл. Соответственно, переписав алгоритм вы уйдете от этой ошибки.

Comment: У меня просто есть программа ,про постройку дома,там очень много переменных типа bool и циклов,по идее все правильно но когда начал добавлять еще 12 циклов и несколько десятков переменных типа bool,программа накрылась)

Comment: @ЛаврикКан, значит косяк в алгоритме. Стандартного стека должно хватать.